# Devo escrever meu programa em inglês ou português?

Tags: convenções-de-nome, estilo-de-codificação

Quando estou escrevendo programas, normalmente eu escrevo os nomes de variáveis em inglês (por exemplo, `fields, class_name, rec_number`), por vários motivos:

- Nomes em inglês não têm acentos, então não fica um negócio estranho como `pontuacao`
- Os nomes normalmente são menores ([ref](http://ecos-da-traducao.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/taxa-de-expansao-de-palavras-e_26.html))
- O código poderá um dia ser mantido por alguém que não fala a língua portuguesa
- As APIs quase sempre são todas em inglês

Porém há outras coisas que eu prefiro manter em português, principalmente se for do contexto do sistema. Comentários, nomes de classes ou tabelas, por exemplo, `class Funcionario`.

Por esse motivo, algumas vezes os nomes em português se misturam com inglês, por exemplo, pode haver uma `class FuncionarioListView`. Enquanto é perfeitamente compreensível, isso me parece estranho.

Levando-se também em consideração que todo programador deve ter noções básicas de inglês, qual é o método preferido para a escolha do idioma que eu devo usar ao programar?

Quais as vantagens de escolher um método ou o outro?

Comment: Isso depende do muito do gosto, algumas vezes vc é obrigado a seguir a padronização da empresa ou do projeto, o importante é NÃO MISTURAR estilos.

Comment: Não interessa o padrão que se siga, contanto que tenha um.

Comment: Eu costumo fazer tudo em Inglês. 

Para casos como `Funcionário`, `Empresa`, eu utilizo `Employee`, `Company`,... o que é bem fácil e óbvio. Mas às vezes torna-se um pouco difícil encontrar alguns termos como CNPJ.  

Neste caso eu uso algo genérico como `companyIdentificationNumber`, e na declaração da variável ou no script SQL (se for um campo do banco de dados) eu coloco algum comentário do tipo:

    `// company identification number used for tax paying purposes
    // CNPJ (Brazil), CUIT (Argentina), EIN (Employer Identification Number in USA), ...
    String companyIdentificationNumber;`

Comment: Eu entendo que possa haver diferenças de estilo e opinião pessoal, mas eu realmente esperava que houvesse um *guideline* ou melhores práticas.

Comment: @AugustoMen Infelizmente, não conheço ninguém que seja **autoritativo** no assunto de modo a publicar um *guideline* que fosse aceito por consenso diante de tantas opiniões divergentes. Não vi isso nem na faculdade, nem na indústria. Conheço **argumentos** contra e a favor do uso do inglês e até mesmo da mistura, mas nada "talhado em pedra". Se a pergunta chegar a ser reaberta, pretendo dar minhas contribuições, mas por mais que tente ser objetivo receio que seria apenas mais uma opinião entre tantas...

Comment: Só um aparte, independente dessa discussão toda: existem linguagens (como Scala) que aceitam acentos em seus identificadores, permitindo, então, `pontuação`.

Comment: Trabalhei em uma empresa onde na minha equipe tinha gente com problemas com inglês, os projetos eram escritos em português. Ou seja, **se inglês for um problema** use português, caso contrário prefira inglês, será consistente com a própria linguagem, Frameworks, Bibliotecas de terceiros, etc.

Comment: Certa vez um conhecido que é gerente de projetos da Yahoo! disse que a primeira coisa a se fazer para se tornar um programador/analista/nome-bonito é saber falar inglês. 99.9% de tudo que é feito na computação é em inglês. Prefira o inglês, quando não der certo, use o que for mais lógico.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Para responder a essa pergunta, você deve determinar ao menos 4 fatores (listados aqui em ordem decrescente de importância, na minha opinião):

1. Trata-se de um projeto interno [de sua empresa, por exemplo], ou algo a ser exposto ao público em geral? (nem que seja apenas a API)
2. Quem vai trabalhar nesse projeto (funcionários? voluntários de qualquer parte do globo?) e qual o seu domínio do inglês?
3. Qual o domínio de aplicação do seu projeto? (i.e. que problema ele resolve) Esse domínio é algo altamente localizado (ex.: algo que precisa ter conformidade com as leis ou regulamentos locais), ou possui caráter global?
4. A linguagem de programação / *framework* / biblioteca é excessivamente verbosa, ou possui convenções em que se repetem muitos nomes em inglês?

### Visibilidade

Pouquíssimos projetos são destinados a um público global, ou ao menos são bem-sucedidos em atingir esse objetivo. A grande maioria dos projetos são para resolver problemas internos, e o software resultante nunca sai da empresa. Do restante, outros tantos são de código fechado, de modo que ainda que o software seja difundido seu código-fonte não o é. E finalmente, existem projetos que - mesmo *open source* - raramente recebem contribuições que não de seu autor/equipe.

Se seu projeto se enquadrar numa das condições acima, e **se houver vantagem** em se desenvolver em português (mais sobre isso adiante), então é contra-produtivo se adotar o inglês somente pela remota possibilidade de alguém que não domina o português precisar mexer nele no futuro. Principalmente se, por estar numa língua estrangeira, ele acabe recebendo uma documentação de pior qualidade - algo que trará mais ônus à compreensão do que os simples nomes no código-fonte. Já que, estritamente falando, são variáveis matemáticas, poderiam ser substituídas por `x`, `y` e  `z` e a lógica do algoritmo permaneceria inalterada (**não estou dizendo** que isso seria uma boa ideia...).

### Contribuidores/Funcionários

Aqueles dentre nós que dominam o inglês temos uma facilidade de "reconhecer" certos nomes que os não falantes dessa língua não têm. Se vemos em um código *handler*, *listener*, *callback*, etc, já sabemos de cara o **propósito** por trás dessas variáveis (**manipular** um evento, **ouvir** [ser notificado de] uma mudança de estado, **receber de volta uma chamada** [da função sendo invocada], etc), ainda que não saibamos ainda dos detalhes. A simples escolha do nome já nos remete muito, facilitando enormemente a compreensão. E se queremos um método para **ler** um arquivo, por exemplo, já procuramos no índice pela letra "R" (*read*).

É difícil para nós imaginar como os não falantes se sentem, mas quem já trabalhou com [ou deu aulas para] pessoas sem o domínio do inglês sabe o quanto a barreira da língua é elevada, e como isso acarreta em mais esforço para se ter um desempenho semelhante. Isso significa que, se quem vai mexer no seu código não possui essa "habilidade ideal", sua equipe vai ser **menos produtiva**. Você (se empregador) vai ter que **pagar mais** e **receber menos** [pelo número extra de desenvolvedores, ainda que cada um deles ganhe menos por não dominar o inglês]. Ainda que você coloque como requisito para contratação a fluência em inglês, o número de candidatos em potencial será menor, tornando mais difícil preencher uma vaga.

Isso pode ser mitigado pelo uso **constante** e **eficiente** do português na sua base de código. As palavras-chave da linguagem não tem como mudar, mas pelo menos os métodos e classes comuns (todo projeto tem uma biblioteca "util", não?) podem receber nomes simples e consistentes, que remetam aos conceitos que seus desenvolvedores já conheçam - ou metáforas que auxiliem a compreensão (como existe por exemplo o `throw` e `catch`, ainda que o gerenciamento de exceções não tenha nada a ver com bolas de *basebol*...).

A estratégia oposta, traduzir para o inglês termos já bem conhecidos e consolidados (não se esqueçam que a **especificação de requisitos** provavelmente estará em português, já que ela é a "ponte" entre os clientes e a equipe de desenvolvimento), podem elevar ainda mais a dificuldade do desenvolvimento, principalmente em equipe (eu "decorei" o termo "Foo" que é usado no meu código, mas meu colega escreveu um trecho usando "Bar" que faz interface com o meu. O que será "Bar"?). Ou seja, se você optar por desenvolver em inglês, esteja preparado para montar uma equipe onde todos tenham fluência tanto no inglês quanto no português [se aplicável].

### Domínio

Essa seção é auto-explicativa. Se eu tenho de gerar os relatórios [DARF](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documento_de_Arrecada%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Receitas_Federais) e [DEGREF](http://ww2.prefeitura.sp.gov.br//arquivos/secretarias/assistencia_social/portarias/ANEXO4PORT30DEGREF_Municip.pdf), com todos os seus campos já expressos em português, não faria o menor sentido usar variáveis em inglês. E seu quero manipular o [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) via uma biblioteca [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), não vai ajudar nada traduzir os conceitos para português...

(Nota: ambas as coisas podem ocorrer no mesmo código - se meu DEGREF está representado em XML, primeiro eu crio uma variável `node_list` para localizar meus elementos, depois os converto em uma `lista_despesas`; a menos que se esteja explicitamente priorizando o português - pelas razões citadas na seção acima - caso em que **talvez** se justifique usar `lista_nós`)

### Convenções

Essa parte é controversa, já que muitas linguagens utilizam o princípio ["Convenção sobre configuração"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conven%C3%A7%C3%A3o_sobre_configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o) (*Convention over configuration - CoC*), às vezes chegando a **impor** certas convenções como *quasi*-mandatórias ou *de facto* mandatórias (ex.: você pode criar um [*Java Bean*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) usando `obterFoo` e `atribuirFoo`, mas muitas ferramentas automatizadas de reflexão não serão capazes de reconhecer `Foo` como uma propriedade). Outras não têm esse tipo de retrição, **desacoplando** os nomes de sua semântica (ex.: em C# você cria blocos `get` e `set` para uma propriedade, mas o código consumidor da classe usa seu nome simples, sem mistura).

Se sua ferramenta (linguagem, biblioteca) é pesada em CoC, de fato misturar inglês com português fica estranho, e deve ser evitado **para todo conceito comum**. Conceitos **pertecentes ao domínio**, por outro lado, podem justificar a "esquisitisse" - uma vez que a associação "esse campo da tela está representado por essa variável" fica mais fácil quando se utiliza uma nomenclatura apropriada.

Há ainda o caso de abreviações, como por exemplo `IFoo` (interface "Foo"), que pessoalmente considero uma concessão razoável quando o acoplamento nome-funcionalidade é inevitável (reconheço que em certos casos promove melhoria da compreensão). Nesse caso, a abreviação acaba se tornando o elemento que remete ao conceito, de modo que ao ver o "I" você já pensa "IFoo não tem métodos concretos" - em vez de haver uma associação indireta, como "IFoo é uma interface, e interfaces não têm métodos concretos".

Por conta desse "atalho de compreensão", não vejo problema algum em usar nomes em português com abreviaturas em inglês (ex.: `FuncionarioLV extends ListView`), uma vez que o "LV" no nome funciona quase como um [***sigil***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29), com as mesmas vantagens [e problemas] que isso acarreta.

---

### Conclusão

Não há problemas em se escrever programas em português, desde que isso seja bem-feito. Particularidades do projeto podem exigir um ou outro idioma, e isso não ocorrerá sem custos. O que se deve evitar é o pensamento reducionista de que "tem que ser em inglês porque quem 'domina' usa inglês", pois se fosse assim todos nós estaríamos falando Latim...

Comment: Demorei para comentar, mas essa foi a resposta mais explanatória e impessoal até o momento.

Comment: @AugustoMen e porque não aceitá-la então?

Comment: @bigown era "até o momento" rsss

Answer (score 33):

Descrever certas ações em inglês é bem mais fácil, ex:

```
setName(string name)
```

Já em português:

- `setNome`, mistura inglês com português.
- `setarNome`, neologismo na palavra *setar*.
- `atribuirNome`, um pouco grande de escrever/ler além de abrir espaço para certas variações (`preencherNome`, `colocarNome`, etc).

Além de outras vantagens (em inglês):

- Possibilidade de qualquer um (diferentes nacionalidades) trabalhar no seu código (essencial se open source).
- Fica bem mais coerente com os nomes das APIs/frameworks que você utilizará, que provavelmente estarão em inglês.

Enfim, no final das contas, escrever inglês é vantajoso em minha opnião. Mas para isso o resto da seu time tem que saber escrever/ler bem em inglês (para não ser mais uma dificuldade).

E claro, **seja consistente**. Assuma uma forma em seu projeto e a mantenha.

Comment: Eu usaria `nome` (getter/setter), ou `nome([novoNome])`, mas depende da linguagem.

Comment: Essa pergunta se responde quando se tem um planejamento antes de iniciar o projeto. A parametrização de classes, funções, variáveis e outros elementos do sistema deve ser discutida anteriormente pela equipe que está produzindo o mesmo.
Mesmo em empresas, se você é obrigado a seguir um padrão é porque isso já foi feito, e se o projeto for seu, é interessante criar um documento de parametrização para manter a organização e o código limpo.

Comment: O problema é quando você tem um `getBoletoCaixaEconomica()`, um `procuraNotaFiscalPorDanfe(Danfe f)` ou um `calculaFreteCorreios()`. Como é que você traduz isso para o inglês de uma forma que o leitor entenda do que diabos o método se trata?

Comment: @Victor Não se traduz nesse caso. Pelo menos no caso de Caixa Econômica e Correios, estes exemplos são de nomes próprios.

Comment: Eu concordo com o @bfavaretto, [CoC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conven%C3%A7%C3%A3o_sobre_configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o) é uma faca de dois gumes, como detalhei na [minha resposta](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/301/devo-escrever-meu-programa-em-ingles-ou-portugues/1829#1829). Algo que deveria facilitar a compreensão, mas acaba contribuindo para o [*gap* (ou fosso) semântico](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fosso_sem%C3%A2ntico)... (como demonstrado pelos exemplos do @Victor)

Answer (score 15):

Eu acho que depende do projeto.

Se for um projeto de código aberto, usar somente inglês é mais adequado, especialmente se o código estiver disponível em algum site global como o GitHub. Se for um projeto fechado, tocado em uma empresa nacional, com equipe que fala português, não vejo problemas em usar português – a menos que toda a equipe ache melhor usar inglês. Se houver alguém na equipe que não domina bem o inglês, nomear tudo nessa língua pode até atrapalhar.

E eu tento evitar ao máximo misturar os dois idiomas, mas é difícil evitar mesmo. O exemplo que você citou me parece aceitável, porque ListView é quase um nome próprio. Mas eu evitaria algo como getFuncionario.

Comment: Mesmo em código aberto, os profissionais envolvidos no projeto devem discutir a parametrização dos elementos de escrita. Caso surja alguma necessidade de alterar esses padrões, outro documento de padronização deve ser criado e então o código deve ser revisado e atualizado.

Comment: @LeandroLUK Concordo. Mas em relação ao idioma, você não acha que inglês é uma unanimidade no mundo open-source? Usar qualquer outro idioma praticamente inviabiliza a participação do resto do mundo no projeto.

Comment: (Opinião pessoal) Mesmo que o mundo utilize o inglês como linguagem padrão, o **br.stackoverflow** foi criado. Sendo assim tanto eu, quanto você, quanto inúmeros outros desenvolvedores não se sentem confortáveis em usar restritamente outra linguagem diferente da que você usa no seu dia-a-dia. O que acha @bfavaretto?

Comment: @LeandroLUK Eu acho que há espaço para tudo (e por isso participo deste site, empolgado), mas que há certas coisas que exigem inglês.

Answer (score 8):

**Use o português** (sempre que possível)

Português é sua língua nativa, portanto você terá menos dúvidas com relação à língua para desenvolver seus projetos. O momento em que você está desenvolvendo não é o momento ideal para você aprender uma nova língua.

Imagine que ao invés de criar classes `Empregador` e `Funcionario` você resolve criar classes `Employer` e `Employee`, que são as tradução respectivamente. Já imaginou se alguém da sua equipe troca as bolas e põe um funcionário no lugar de um empregador ou vice-versa? As chances de erro aumentam consideravelmente.

Todo programador sabe as palavras básicas do inglês: if, switch, class, set, get, etc; mas as demais palavras vai depender do conhecimento de cada um em inglês. Imagine se você precisar criar variáveis que os nomes sejam **[falsos cognatos](http://www.sk.com.br/sk-fals.html)**? Já pensou a confusão se formando? Eu não arriscaria adicionar bugs ao meu projeto por problemas de comunicação dentro de uma equipe que todo mundo fala nativamente o português. Me diz: Pra quê complicar?

Quanto à `setNome`, `setEndereco`, não vejo o menor problema com isso, já que `set` e `get` são convenções que utilizamos constantemente para fazer nossos `getters and setters`, essas palavras são (ou devem ser) tão naturais para desenvolvedores como qualquer outra palavra reservada.

Answer (score 6):

Se você for programador e as regras já estiverem postas por pessoas hierarquicamente superiores, só te resta segui-las.

Agora, se você for responsável ou for um dos responsáveis por definir essas regras, você deve analisar você, seu ambiente e o melhor custo-benefício de cada escolha.

Aliás, não acho que você deveria se limitar a escolher entre "português" ou "inglês". Padronizar a escrita de código é algo que vai além disso; por exemplo, você pode definir que nomes de métodos e funções sempre começarão com verbos e que siglas sempre terão apenas a primeira letra maiúscula (como `Html`).

Eu sugiro pensar dessa forma, e não apenas ficar em dúvida entre "inglês" e "português".

Tente identificar as necessidades e tente fazer uma lista de **requisitos** que devem ser cumpridos, com intuito de solucionar o maior número de problemas possíveis:

- Você trabalha em uma equipe? Se sim, o que os membros da equipe acham de cada escolha? Eles tem proficiência o suficiente para escrever em inglês? Eles tem proficiência o suficiente para escrever em português? Eles sabem ou querem usar um tradutor?
- Consistência e simplicidade: Em geral, fazer uma definição simples e consistente e segui-la de forma correta é desejável, pois facilita a programação: padrões consistentes e simples permitem que os programadores deduzam facilmente nomes de variáveis, classes etc.
- Padronização pré-existente: Eventualmente, você pode trabalhar em uma empresa que já usa uma determinada padronização para diversos projetos e bibliotecas que serão utilizados no seu projeto. Dessa forma, seguir as mesmas regras já existentes - caso elas estejam sendo satisfatórias - pode ser desejável.
- Cultura: Dependendo da linguagem que você está utilizando, pode haver uma **cultura** dos programadores utilizarem um determinado tipo de padrão. Nesse sentido, seguir esse padrão pode trazer diversos benefícios, como facilitar a integração de um novo programador já acostumado com a cultura da linguagem no projeto.
- Algum outro requisito mais específico para seu caso: as vezes, você simplesmente tem um chefe que prefere de um jeito e não de outro; mesmo que ele não participe ativamente do projeto. ;)

Em geral, não existe nenhuma situação em que utilizar determinada abordagem "ganhe" em todos esses requisitos; cabe a você analisar e descobrir quais desses requisitos são mais importantes e escolher a partir disso. Ainda, pensar dessa forma ajuda a você relatar e justificar suas escolhas caso haja essa necessidade. Por exemplo:

> Escolhi utilizar nomes em português porque 30% dos programadores da equipe não sabem inglês, e os outros 70% não vêem problema em utilizar português.

Answer (score 6):

Como profissional você esta tentando atingir seu melhor, e o melhor neste caso é o inglês.

Algumas vezes você é membro de uma equipe e não cabe a você decidir isso, mas você deve deixar clara sua opinião.

Eu costumo me forçar a descrever tudo em inglês, inclusive comentários, entidades de domínio, tudo. Incentivo também outras pessoas a fazerem o mesmo.

## Vantagens

1. Isso melhora seu inglês
2. Linguagem utilizam construções em inglês o que deixa a leitura mais natural e homogenia.
3. Quase toda literatura sai antes em inglês do que português, todas as novas tecnologias saem em
   inglês antes, os melhores livros, os melhores blogs estão em inglês . Se você lê bastante livros
   técnicos, os melhores autores provavelmente escreveram tudo em inglês .
4. Muitas coisa na vida geram mais liberdade e mais possibilidades. Aprender a andar, ler, se comunicar com eficiência, aprender a dirigir todas estas coisas geram isso. Com o inglês é a mesma coisa, ele vai te dar mais liberdade profissional e pessoal.
5. Você para de pensar que seu software vai ficar só na empresa e começa a pensar que seu software pode atingir outros lugares. De qualquer forma você já vai estar preparado

Resumindo:

> Se você esta preocupado em melhorar como profissional não aceite fazer as coisas pela média.

Existe um [post](http://www.akitaonrails.com/2007/04/14/off-topic-seja-arrogante) interessante sobre isso no blog do Akita que recomendo.

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que depende da equipe em que você trabalha.

Eu prefiro programar em inglês (entre outros motivos, para evitar a mistura de idiomas e para evitar neologismos estranhos), mas tem pessoas na minha equipe que não gostam (dizem que se estamos no Brasil tem que ser tudo em Português...).

E além da sua equipe atual, você precisa levar em consideração de que a próxima equipe que dará manutenção no código pode não entender praticamente nada de inglês, ou pelo contrário: podem estar acostumada com os padrões internacionais e estranharem adaptações para nosso idioma (eu por exemplo, até hoje estranho quando vejo "dese" em vez de "dev" para se referir a desenvolvimento/development).

No final das contas, **o mais importante é a legibilidade do código** (pelo menos essa é a minha opinião).

Comment: +1 por "o mais importante é a legibilidade do código" =)

Answer (score 4):

É comum a mesclagem das línguas como você mencionou no exemplo "class Funcionario", porem uma boa prática é não misturar as línguas em um mesmo nome como "FuncionarioListView", só que ao mesmo tempo você se contradiz em um dos pontos que levantou "O código poderá ser mantido por alguém que não fala a língua portuguesa", quando isto é levado em conta acredito que deve-se codificar somente em inglês.

Answer (score 4):

Por mais que você saiba inglês, ele pode ser uma armadilha em grandes programas que tenham relações, ações ou objetos não costumeiros. No mundo "dos códigos", uma hora você irá se perguntar: "como se chama isto?" e perder tempo procurando. Se for como eu (quer ver a coisa funcionar logo), irá misturar as línguas. É claro que o mesmo problema ocorre em português, mas é mais fácil achar, corrigir ou refatorar se nomeado dentro de um padrão.
No entanto, se for um código para a comunidade, não tem jeito: tem que ser inglês.

Answer (score 3):

É, ver a mistura dos idiomas acaba sendo natural por que nós falamos português, e quase todos os ambientes e linguagens de programação tem base em inglês. Acredito que o melhor para estes casos é tentar utilizar a nomenclatura em inglês pelo fato de que todos os termos da linguagem também são em inglês, para não gerar a mistura de línguas. Mas isso é uma questão de opinião :)

Answer (score 3):

Por padrão, boas práticas, e visando uma maior manutenibilidade do código, o mais recomendado é em inglês.

Mas isso depende de um simples fator: o que você está utilizando para desenvolver?

## Inglês

Querendo ou não, o inglês é o idioma universal. Com isso, é extremamente recomendável que desde já (ainda mais quem trabalha com TI), você saiba ao menos o inglês técnico.

Isso facilita por sua vez, você encontrar tutoriais na internet, novos trabalhos, participar de um projeto no exterior, etc.

Portando, além do fato de ser praticamente um pré-requisito para a nossa área, criar algo em inglês permite a você (e ao seu projeto) ter participação de qualquer pessoa do mundo, que neste caso um GRANDE AVANÇO, como por exemplo projetos **open source** no Github.

---

## Equipe

O ideal é conversar com sua equipe, para entrar em um consenso, para que com isso o projeto não seja prejudicado por simplesmente nome de métodos e/ou comentários.

---

## Frameworks

#### MVC

A grande maioria dos frameworks estão em inglês, e são preparados para compreender tudo que você cria (controllers, models, views) neste mesmo idioma. Sendo assim, se o seu controller se chamar Usuários, na maioria das vezes o framework não irá entender que seu model se chamará Usuário.

#### Banco de Dados

Grande parte dos geradores de código compreendem perfeitamente suas tabelas, se elas estiverem nomeadas seguindo a convenção deles e em inglês. Com isso, se você tem uma tabela que se chama `users`, ele já irá criar tranquilamente seu controller (Users), model (User) e views (Users/show, Users/edit, Users/create, Users/index).

---

## Dica

Em projetos que já trabalhei, para que o desenvolvimento fosse mais rápido, optamos (eu e a equipe) de manter a nomenclatura de tudo em inglês, assim como sugere grande partes dos frameworks.

**Porém**, todos os comentários eram em português, facilitando assim o entendimento pelos membros da equipe que não dominavam o inglês técnico.

---

Espero ter ajudado.