# Existe algum problema em usar caracteres Unicode para identificadores em código?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, acentuação, unicode

Hoje é comum os compiladores das linguagens de programação permitirem que o arquivo de código de seus programas aceitem código com caracteres Unicode.

Isto é útil, especialmente para quem usa o português e outras línguas que fogem do ASCII para criar *strings* com acentos e melhorar os comentários em nossa língua.

Mas é incomum o uso de identificadores com acentos no código. Há até mesmo quem recomende que não seja usado.

Eu mesmo não costumo usar, mas me parece que dar um sentido melhor nestes casos (só um exemplo isolado sem definição de linguagem):

```
class Validação {
    bool ÉValido;
    ...
}
```

Existe algum motivo técnico para evitar acentos e outros caracteres Unicode em identificadores?

Se não existe problema técnico, existe algum motivo prático para evitá-los?

Depende da linguagem de programação? Considerando que ela suporte bem acentuação em plenitude.

Importa se o código é proprietário e desenvolvido por uma equipe pequena e fechada ou se é desenvolvido amplamente, possivelmente de forma aberta?

Existe algum cuidado específico que devemos tomar quando usamos acentos em identificadores?

Quando a utilização de caracteres além do ASCII é abuso?

Comment: Fiz esta pergunta até para demonstrar como deixar adequado algo que pode dar margem para amplitude e opiniões. Programadores também precisam aprender criar especificações, seja em programas ou perguntas, negociar com seus pares, defender seus argumentos, contornar obstáculos sem ferir regras estabelecidas, se comunicar para que todos entendam. Tem que demonstrar esforço e necessidade real para a pergunta. A maioria das perguntas fechadas poderiam ser salvas se isto fosse feito sempre. Alguns casos terceiros podem salvar, outras só o OP pode fazer isto.

Comment: Curiosa tag, `estilo-de-codificação`, ela aparece como uma das suas 3 top tags [nesta página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)... Outro que tem uma tag curiosa é o Math, `string`, who the heck é master em string? :D

Comment: @brasofilo eu :D http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/string/topusers Estou quase ganhando medalha por ela :D

Comment: @brasofilo hahahahaha... Eu já pensei nisso tb. Pior q toda vez q eu respondo uma pergunta de String ela fica bem pontuada. Minhas duas unicas medalhas de "resposta legal" são de String :p

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Quando se fala em utilizar elementos sintáticos em geral (e não somente identificadores) que vão além do ASCII, há uma série de fatores a serem considerados:

1. O compilador precisa oferecer suporte apropriado para entradas Unicode. Isso vai além da simples codificação (*encoding*) dos caracteres: é necessário saber se o suporte [se limita ao BMP](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/P6zc2/) ou [se estende aos SMPs](https://ideone.com/U549nr), se ele [trata bem de *surrogate pairs*](https://ideone.com/gDWKDn), se ele trabalha com [caracteres combinantes ou somente com pré-compostos](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/auQe2/), se ele aceita [caracteres de escape no código fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4448180/520779) ou não. Podem existir outras considerações, isso é apenas o que me vem à memória.

   Um exemplo seria a forma como a palavra "árvore" é representada em Unicode:

   ```
   '\xe1rvore',    // Latin Small Letter A with acute,              r,v,o,r,e
   'a\u0301rvore', // Latin Small Letter A, Combining Acute Accent, r,v,o,r,e
   ```

   Se uma biblioteca foi escrita num editor que usa pré-compostos, e o código que tenta usá-la foi escrito num que usa combinantes, o identificador pode não ser reconhecido.
2. A linguagem faz distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas ou não? Se a resposta for não, há o problema do *collation*: a menos que o computador onde o código está sendo compilado possua o mesmo *locale* do computador onde originalmente esse código foi concebido, pode ocorrer do mesmo identificador ser interpretado de formas diferentes ao normalizar a capitalização. [Exemplo](https://ideone.com/HrHZ5P):

   ```
   "mail".toUpperCase(); // MAİL (Turco)
                         // MAIL (Resto do mundo)
   ```

   De novo, se uma biblioteca foi compilada num computador com o locale Turco, e quem vai usá-la não tem esse locale, os identificadores podem  não ser reconhecidos (quando o compilador tentar normalizá-los).
3. Quão difícil é fazer a entrada de caracteres Unicode? Para nós, que usamos português, entrar com caracteres acentuados é fácil - nosso próprio leiaute de teclado dá suporte a isso. Mas se fôssemos usar uma biblioteca com identificadores em japonês, por exemplo, como faríamos? Da mesma forma, outras pessoas podem ter dificuldades em digitar letras acentuadas, mas todo mundo possui no mínimo um bom suporte a ASCII.

Isso significa que usar identificadores Unicode é sempre ruim? Não. Depende muito mais do **escopo** do sistema sendo desenvolvido. Tal como no caso de ["escrever ou não em português"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/301/215), há uma série de fatores que ajudam a determinar se é aceitável ou não que o sistema tenha um escopo mais local - ainda que *a princípio* isso fosse excludente em relação ao público global (veja [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1829/215) à pergunta linkada para mais detalhes). É útil escrever programas em português, e é útil que estes sejam escritos em português correto. De modo que, na ausência de problemas em contrário, não vejo razão para não usar caracteres além do ASCII.

- Explicitando: se toda a equipe de desenvolvimento usar o mesmo editor de texto ou IDE, o problema 1 praticamente não existe (a menos que se programe em chinês tradicional); se todos estiverem no mesmo *locale*, o problema 2 não se aplica; e se todos usarem o mesmo padrão de teclado, o 3 não coloca ninguém em "desvantagem". Ou seja, esses fatores são bem menos relevantes para um projeto *in-house* do que para um aberto ao público.

**Adendo:** por que não falei sobre o problema do *encoding*, no sentido de um programador editar em um e outro programador editar em outro? Porque isso é um problema *muito mais geral* - que afeta inclusive os **comentários** no código. A necessidade da equipe de desenvolvimento de utilizar sempre o mesmo *encoding* é global, de modo que não se trata de empecilho para usar identificadores Unicode se assim se desejar.

Comment: Nota: como aspirante a projetista de uma linguagem de programação, já pensei muito a respeito desse dilema (bem como sobre usar ou não *case-insensitive*). Tenho umas ideias interessantes a respeito (é necessário "pensar fora da caixa" e quebrar alguns tabus), mas não dá pra entrar muito em detalhes aqui, porque seria somente opinião e/ou especulação...

Comment: E há algum modo de descobrirmos estas ideias? :)

Comment: @bigown Em breve... Ainda não estou pronto pra divulgar detalhes do meu projeto, e seria por demais extenso pra expor aqui. Simplificando bastante, seria uma questão de normalizar os identificadores (e outros nomes) de modo a garantir a interoperabilidade. Ou seja, assim como em SQL `select` == `SELECT`, teríamos `árvore` == `arvore`. Isso ameniza o problema 3. Quanto ao 1 e 2, deixo uma pergunta pra reflexão: é mesmo necessário que os códigos fontes sejam sempre representados em arquivo por texto plano? (já até pensei em discutir isso aqui, mas creio que é por demais subjetiva pro site)

Comment: Isto é sacanagem :P

Comment: De qualquer forma, quis me ater ao que é de interesse do desenvolvedor hoje, e não especular sobre o futuro (afinal essa é uma pergunta de "estilo de codificação", não de "design de linguagem" ou "projeto de compiladores"). P.S. Adicionei vários exemplos na resposta - em Java (ideone) e JavaScript (jsFiddle) - *demonstrando* os problemas na prática. E uma nota esclarecendo que, para um projeto local, eles não são tão ruins quanto parecem.

Answer (score 18):

A maioria dos ambientes modernos de fato suporta trabalhar com unicode. Mas daí para usar isso no código tem um grande espaço. O primeiro ponto a considerar antes de pensar na estética e nas boas práticas, é se a sua linguagem suporta isso. A maioria define um conjunto finito (e pequeno) de caracteres dos quais o código fonte deve ser composto. Geralmente é um subconjunto do ASCII. Por exemplo, o standard do C diz o seguinte (C11, 5.2.1/3):

> Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have the following
>   members: the 26 uppercase letters of the Latin alphabet
>
> ```
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M
> N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> ```
>
> the 26 lowercase letters of the Latin alphabet
>
> ```
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m
> n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> ```
>
> the 10 decimal digits
>
> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```
>
> the following 29 graphic characters
>
> ```
> ! " # % & ' ( ) * + , - . / :
> ; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~
> ```

Usar qualquer coisa fora disso seria inválido. Um compilador pode aceitar, claro. E a maioria aceita. Mas se quer um código portável e que vá funcionar em qualquer plataforma, é bom se restringir.

Outra problemática é a codificação do arquivo. Pode acontecer de dois arquivos do mesmo programa estarem salvos com codificações diferentes (por qualquer motivo que seja). Visualmente você verá o caractere `É` em ambos, mas na hora de executar, pode ser que o compilador/interpretador veja diferentes identificadores ali. No fim você terá um erro bastante difícil de rastrear, já que a mensagem de erro não vai ajudar.

Uma linguagem que suporta amplamente escrever código com caracteres não ASCII é o Ruby. O parser e demais ferramentas foram construídas com isso em mente e não há um conjunto limitante de caracteres permitidos. Isso abre espaço para algumas coisas interessantes, como demonstra o artigo [**Unicode Whitespace Shenigans for Rubyists**](http://www.rubyinside.com/the-split-is-not-enough-whitespace-shenigans-for-rubyists-5980.html) de Peter Cooper:

> Usando um símbolo unicode para o espaço (o mesmo do `&nbsp;` do HTML):
>
> [image]
>   <sub>(fonte: [no.gd](http://no.gd/awesome.png))</sub>
>
> Ele não é visto como um espaço, vira parte do identificador. Permite escrever algo tão confuso quanto isso:
>
> [image]
>   <sub>(fonte: [no.gd](http://no.gd/awesome2.png))</sub>
>
> Já que temos uma plenitude de caracteres de espaço para usar:
>
> [image]
>   <sub>(fonte: [rubyinside.com](http://www.rubyinside.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/spaced.png))</sub>

Usar unicode em uma codebase abre espaço para alguns absurdos e bugs complicadíssimos de rastrear. Outro problema claro está em tentar copiar e colar o código em ferramentas diferentes. Nunca se sabe o que pode acontecer.

Problemas técnicos de lado, tem sempre a questão da linguagem (a falada). Se é um projeto grande, ou que vire a ser opensource, é sempre recomendado utilizar o inglês no código, abolindo o uso de unicode.

Já em um projeto pequeno com uma equipe de poucos desenvolvedores, há bastante espaço para que regras sejam definidas e convenções próprias sejam criadas. Havendo um acordo entre todos, não há motivo para não. Lembrando de sempre pesar os prós e contras de adotar esse estilo.

---

Um caso que já vi acontecer e que considero de certa forma válido é na hora de escrever testes. Em muitos frameworks você define uma função/membro/método que vai ser um bloco de asserts a serem executados. Quando um falha, geralmente o nome dessa função é exibido na tela como o nome do teste que falhou. Como essa é uma função que você nunca chama explicitamente, usar espaços-unicode no nome pode ser interessante. Vai deixar a saída de erro bastante mais legível.

Comment: Nesse exemplo do Ruby, IMHO a culpa é totalmente do Ruby, não do Unicode: se numa linguagem "somente ASCII" um identificador é `[\w_]+` (i.e. letras, números e underscore) numa linguagem "Unicode" um identificador deveria ser `[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]+` (idem). Permitir **qualquer tipo** de caractere como parte do identificador é querer procurar problema...

Comment: "Pra variar" aqui tem respostas melhores do que achamos em inglês :)

Comment: @bigown quase me voto negativamente depois da segunda resposta, haha