# Existem vantagens objetivas em uma linguagem ser "case sensitive" ou não?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, design-de-linguagem, case-insensitive, sensibilidade-de-caixa

Ou será que isto é apenas gosto?

Não quero se você gosta mais de um do que outro. [Não quero saber porque as pessoas gostam mais de uma ou outra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/165455/221800). [Não quero achismos ou respostas rasas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/521349/221800). [Não quero saber razões históricas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503218/221800).

Quero saber de forma fundamentada o que se ganha ou se perde em cada uma das abordagens.

Exemplos de linguagens sensíveis: C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Python, Ruby, Objective C.

Exemplos de linguagens insensíveis: SQL, COBOL, BASIC (acho que todos os dialetos), PHP (bom, sei lá, em parte), e [Clipper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101) e dialetos.

Esta pergunta tem relação com [essa outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16555/101).

Só para deixar claro para quem não entende do assunto, estou falando da sintaxe da linguagem. Falo das palavras-chave, dos identificadores.

Comment: Eu continuo tentando escrever uma resposta. Mantenha decidir é apenas opinião . Eu pensei que com o novo status para o site, on- tema se tornaria mais apertado.

Comment: Eu não tinha escutado ainda essa dupla: "linguagens sensíveis".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A principal vantagem do *case sensitive* é aumentar o conjunto de símbolos (nomes) possíveis. O principal impacto nas linguagens tradicionais é a criação de uma relação implícita entre um tipo e uma instância desse tipo. Outro menos empregado (Prolog, Erlang) é a possibilidade de dar tratamento semântico diferenciado dependendo da capitalização. Por fim, há questões práticas envolvendo a compilação e gestão do *runtime*, em que a implementação de uma linguagem *case sensitive* é mais simples.

A principal vantagem do *case insensitive* é a facilidade de memorização dos símbolos da linguagem, e a consequente redução dos erros relacionados à capitalização incorreta.

### Tipos vs. instâncias

Na linguagem natural, um nome tem a função de representar unicamente um conceito. Há colisões (ex.: manga fruta ou manga da camisa), mas elas são raras e normalmente se remove a ambiguidade pelo contexto. Numa linguagem formal (ex.: vocabulário controlado, taxonomia, *thesaurus*, ontologia) a unicidade dos nomes é obrigatória, e isso se aplica especialmente a programas de computador - onde a ambiguidade seria um empecilho para o tratamento automatizado do texto.

Entretanto, a ambiguidade não é sempre ruim: na presença de **contexto**, usar o mesmo nome para representar coisas distintas - porém relacionadas - não só causa pouco prejuízo como também é útil. Se eu digo "cachorro" isso se remete a um tipo de animal. Se eu digo "um cachorro" falo de um espécime desse mesmo animal. Se digo "o cachorro" não só é um espécime qualquer desse animal, mas um específico, que talvez já tenha sido mencionado anteriormente ou então seja único dado o contexto (ex.: se há somente um cachorro num conjunto de animais). Isso facilita a comunicação.

Da mesma forma na programação se busca muito a concisão, já que ela é uma medida da **expressividade** da linguagem. Porém, essa concisão precisa sempre ser pesada contra a clareza do código ("programas são feitos para humanos lerem e só incidentalmente para computadores executarem"). Na ausência desses "atalhos" semânticos, busca-se outras formas de fazer o nome de algo remeter a um conceito:

- *sigils* (`$foo` é um escalar, `@foo` é um array);
- Notação húngara (`iSize` é um inteiro, `szLastName` é uma string terminada em nulo);
- Convenções de nomes (`IFoo` é uma interface, `_foo` é um campo privado).
- etc.

Essas convenções são em geral **implícitas**, mas acabam por cumprir o papel de auxiliar na comunicação da semântica do código para os leitores humanos. E uma convenção semelhante, bastante similar ao caso da linguagem natural mencionado acima, é usar o mesmo nome para se referir a um tipo e uma instância desse tipo:

```java
cachorro = new Cachorro();
```

Numa linguagem *case insensitive*, seria necessário usar outro nome, e muito provavelmente o programador escolheria algo como:

```java
oCachorro = new Cachorro();
cachorro1 = new Cachorro();
```

O que torna o código menos legível. E a propósito, essa tendência dos programadores de usar o mesmo nome pra classe e pro objeto fica evidente quando a classe tem o mesmo nome de uma palavra reservada. Veja se isso parece familiar:

```java
clazz = new Class();
```

Escolher nomes é difícil. Alguém poderia insistir "ora, mas é só dar um nome diferente pra variável, tipo `rex = new Cachorro()`", mas na prática isso dificulta a compreensão. Mesmo que o programador se atenha a um estilo particular de codificação (classe começa com maiúscula, variável com minúscula, constante é tudo maiúscula) ele perde essa associação semântica implícita do tipo com a instância. Ou no mínimo é forçado a adotar uma convenção diferente, como as exemplificadas acima.

### Semântica diferenciada

Na maioria das linguagens qualquer diferença entre símbolos capitalizados ou não é puramente convencional. Mas nada impede - e eu sou da opinião que seria um grande avanço - que o compilador "force" essa convenção (como sugerido na [resposta do Victor Stafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74480/215)). Isso não só cria consistência como pode aumentar a expressividade, como acontece por exemplo na linguagem Prolog.

Prolog (e outras linguagens inspiradas nesta, como Erlang) faz distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas e - no caso específico da *primeira letra do nome* - dá um tratamento semântico diferenciado para o mesmo: `foo` é um "átomo" (constante) e `Foo` é uma variável. Isso parece um detalhe bobo, mas na minha experiência com essa linguagem o ganho em expressividade é enorme.

A título de exemplo, algumas linguagens modernas possuem uma característica chamada *destructuring assignment/bind*, como por exemplo Python:

```python
for chave,valor in dicionario.items():
```

Se Python desse suporte à unificação tal como Prolog, seria possível fazer ao mesmo tempo um *destructuring bind*, uma verificação de tipos e até mesmo uma filtragem em uma única expressão:

```python
# Assumindo uma estrutura de dados Cachorro(nome, raca, idade)

for chave,Cachorro(nome, MALTES, sqrt(4)) in dicionario.items():
    print(nome)

# que seria equivalente a:

for chave,valor in dicionario.items():
    if isinstance(valor, Cachorro):
        nome = valor.nome
        if valor.raca == MALTES: # Assumindo que MALTES é uma constante global
            if valor.idade == sqrt(4):
                print(nome)
```

Se a linguagem fosse *case insensitive*, por outro lado, essa unificação não seria possível. Como o compilador saberia que:

- Não é pra chamar `Cachorro(...)` como uma função, mas `sqrt(...)` sim;
- `nome` é uma variável, que deve receber como valor o primeiro campo da instância sendo iterada;
- Já `MALTES` é uma constante, que deve ser comparada com o segundo campo da instância sendo iterada?

Note que tudo isso poderia ser feito como *sigils*, *quotes* (ex.: Lisp), etc, mas repare como o código fica "limpo" sem a poluição visual dos símbolos especiais por toda parte.

(P.S. Um exemplo mais *"relatable"* é o caso das expressões regulares: `\w` pega uma classe de caracteres, `\W` nega essa classe. Se regexes fossem *case insensitive* se teria de "gastar" um símbolo a mais, tornando a linguagem um pouco menos densa.)

### Memorização e capitalização incorreta

Já é difícil memorizar os nomes de todas as classes, funções, etc de uma API, de modo a ser produtivo na mesma sem ter que ficar toda hora voltando pra consultar uma referência. Se o uso da capitalização não for *muito* consistente, acaba-se por ter que memorizar também a mesma, e isso não é algo a ser subestimado: nosso cérebros são bons pra memorizar conceitos (e os orientais são ainda melhores que os ocidentais), mas nem tanto pra memorizar símbolos e grafias:

- Se você tentar memorizar "dona de casa", provavelmente seu cérebro armazenará isso como uma sequência de sons (ˈdɔ nɑ dɪ ˈkɑ sə).
- Um oriental poderia memorizar isso como uma imagem, o que é ainda mais fácil (婦).
- Já um programador teria de se preocupar também com a forma de escrevê-la:

  - `dona de casa`? Não, pois identificadores não podem ter mais de uma palavra;
  - `dona-de-casa`? Não, pois `-` é um operador;
  - `dona_de_casa`? Pode ser... ou seria `donaDeCasa`?
  - `DonaDeCasa`? `DONA_DE_CASA`? Deixa ver, estou tratando de uma variável, classe ou constante?

Se uma linguagem seguir uma convenção rígida de capitalização, e principalmente se o compilador impuser essas regras (como também já abordado na resposta do Victor) então o problema não é tão grande. Mas quando se começa a usar acrônimos a coisa fica mais complicada:

- `IDCachorro` ou `IdCachorro`?
- `UTF8Regex`, `Utf8Regex`, `UTF8RegEx` ou `Utf8RegEx`?

A menos que o compilador saiba o que é um `ID`, que existe algo chamado `UTF8`, que `regex` significa `REGular EXpression`, etc, nada impede que um programador defina algo perfeitamente válido dentro do estilo de codificação de uma linguagem, e outro programador não saiba como soletrá-lo...

A frustração com essa situação tem sido um dos argumentos mais apresentados em favor do *case-insensitive*. Por consistência, há quem defenda [*case-preserving, case-insensitive*](http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2005/10/27/the-case-for-case-preserving-case-insensitivity/), que no meu entendimento significa "não importa a capitalização, mas após um símbolo ser declarado pela primeira vez exija que ele sempre seja grafado da mesma maneira". Pessoalmente, vejo isso como o pior dos dois mundos: perde-se todas as vantagens do *case sensitive*, mas continua-se obrigando o programador a memorizar a grafia do nome... (ou estaria minha interpretação desse conceito incorreta?)

De todo modo, há ao menos uma vantagem inequívoca no *case insensitive*: se a API definiu `RegEx` e o programador escreveu `Regex`, ele não vai tratar ambos como se fossem coisas distintas. Se a linguagem exigir que toda variável/tipo/etc seja declarado, e não permitir que o mesmo seja declarado mais de uma vez, não há problema (caso contrário se estaria simplesmente trocando falsos negativos por falsos positivos). Facilita-se o processo de aprendizado da linguagem e suas APIs, em troca de uma redução no conjunto de nomes usáveis.

### Questões práticas

Por fim, há as implicações práticas de se adotar um ou outro modo. Boa parte delas já foi descrita tanto na resposta do Victor quanto na [minha resposta à pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16572/215): o esforço maior por parte do compilador/interpretador para normalizar os nomes (em relação ao Unicode), convertê-los para uma forma única e realizar o [*interning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). Mas mais importante que essa complexidade ao implementar (que por sinal é função do computador mesmo, tornar a vida dos humanos mais fácil, mesmo que o projetista do compilador tenha de se esforçar mais pra isso) é a questão da localização, em que o mesmo programa pode ter uma interpretação diferente caso mudanças de capitalização sejam parte integrante do seu processo de compilação.

A título de exemplo, numa linguagem *case insensitive* como um compilador no locale turco trataria nomes como `MAİL` e `maıl`? E como um compilador "internacional" trataria os mesmos? A expectativa do programador turco seria atendida ou frustrada por qualquer um dos compiladores, e qual? Como usuário de sistemas que nem sempre tratam bem do Unicode, sei como esses detalhes podem encher o saco e fazer passar raiva. Se tivesse que me preocupar com eles também ao desenvolver (em que minha atenção está toda "gasta" com o problema em mãos) creio que acabaria por rejeitar uma linguagem que não tratasse muito bem disso...

### Conclusão

Os *tradeoffs* me parece ser basicamente os seguintes:

- Facilidade de memorização (*case insensitive*) vs. expressividade semântica (*case sensitive*);
- Falsos positivos (*case insensitive*) vs. falsos negativos (*case sensitive*) ao determinar se dois nomes se referem à mesma coisa.

E as demais características da linguagem têm influencia nesses fatores, por vezes melhorando de um lado e piorando do outro. Ex.: se Python se tornasse *case insensitive* aumentaria o número de colisões de nomes de variáveis, e se pra contrabalancear isso a declaração de variáveis se tornasse obrigatória (ex.: `var RegEx`) reduziria-se a concisão.

Comment: Era o que eu estava esperando. Excelente.

Comment: Bacana mas fiquei confuso numa parte. Você diz: *"cachorro = new Cachorro(); Numa linguagem case insensitive, seria necessário usar outro nome"*, mas VB.Net, case insensitive, aceita `Dim cachorro As Cachorro = New Cachorro()`, bem como aceita `Dim Cachorro As Cachorro = New Cachorro()`, e Java e C#, ambos case sensitive, também aceitam `Cachorro Cachorro = new Cachorro();`. Estas linguagens sabem que trata-se de um nome de variável pelo contexto e não colidem o nome da variável com o nome da classe, mesmo os nomes sendo idênticos ou variando apenas em letter case.

Comment: Me lembrei agora de uma linguagem popular no Brasil que se eu bem me lembro (faz tempo que não uso) não permite declarar a variável com o mesmo nome que a classe - o Delphi. Lá isso não chega a ser um problema porque há o padrão de se declarar classes prefixando-a com "T" de "type" (o que eu particularmente acho bem chatinho). De qualquer modo, me parece tratar-se de uma limitação do compilador e não uma falta natural das linguagens case insensitive.

Comment: @Caffé De fato, numa linguagem estaticamente tipada - em que o *namespace* das variáveis/objetos e o *namespace* dos tipos são disjuntos - não há problema em se ter um tipo e uma variável com o mesmo nome. Da mesma forma, tem linguagens em que uma variável pode ter o mesmo nome de uma *keyword*, desde que fique claro pela sintaxe o que é o que. Apenas quando os tipos são membros de primeira classe é que o conflito aparece (i.e. a linguagem permite que você guarde um tipo numa variável? O tipo mesmo, um objeto do tipo `Class` não conta...).

Comment: De todo modo, a premissa básica continua valendo: se em VB.Net você pode ter tipo `Cachorro` e variável `cachorro`, em Java você pode ter tipos `Cachorro` e `cachorro` e variáveis `cachorro` e `Cachorro`. O universo de nomes possíveis se reduz drasticamente quando se adota o *case insensitive*. Cabe notar entretanto que isso não é necessariamente uma coisa ruim.

Answer (score 11):

Uma vantagem da linguagem ser *case sensitive* é que é mais fácil de forçar regras de nomenclatura de código. Apesar disso, nenhuma das linguagens que você citou que são *case sensitive* acaba por forçar regras de nomenclatura, e não conheço nenhuma que chegou a ver a luz do dia que faça.

Um exemplo, em uma linguagem *case sensitive* que venha a forçar regras de nomenclatura similares ao do Java (só como exemplo), se eu tentasse declarar uma variável com um nome começando com maiúscula, receberia erro de compilação. Se eu tentasse declarar uma classe com nome começando com minúscula também. Entretanto, o fato de estas linguagens **não** forçarem as regras de nomenclatura, faz com que elas percam esta vantagem, pois continuo podendo declarar o nome de uma classe com letra minúscula ou o nome de uma variável com letra maiúscula, desobedecendo as convenções da linguagem.

Por outro lado as desvantagens são muitas. Torna-se mais difícil aprender as linguagens *case sensitive*, pois é difícil para os iniciantes se acostumar a ideia de que `fileName`, `FileName`, `filename` e `FILENAME` são coisas diferentes. Mesmo quem é mais experiente por vezes acaba cometendo erros de trocar alguma maiúscula ou minúscula que o compilador vai pegar... se a linguagem for compilada!

Se a linguagem for interpretada, *case sensistive* e permitir declaração implícita de variáveis, tal como ocorre com o javascript, se você sem querer utilizar `resultARray` ao invés de `resultArray`, você vai ter dor-de-cabeça e vai perder bastante tempo com *debugging*. Isso ocorre porque naturalmente as linguagens *case sensitive* permitem que existam identificadores no mesmo escopo diferindo apenas por maiúsculas/minúsculas, fazendo com que `resultARray` e `resultArray` sejam variáveis diferentes. Mas pior que isso, é quando você pega aquele código todo gambiarrado escrito por algum idiota que usa em um mesmo escopo as variáveis `xy`, `Xy`, `XY` e `xY` com propósitos e finalidades completamente diferentes.

É verdade que o fato da linguagem ser *case sensitive* inibe o programador de escrever código de forma inconsiste e a prestar atenção nas maiúsculas e minúsculas, o que deveria deixar o código com um aspecto mais uniforme. Entretanto, programadores ruins sempre vão dar um jeito de codificar identificadores com nomenclatura inconsistente em linguagens *case sensitive* e programadores bons sempre vão dar um jeito de codificar identificadores com nomenclatura consistente mesmo em linguagens *case insensitive*.

Então, vamos resumir o que é bom:

- Forçar uma regra de nomenclatura que deixe o código uniforme. Linguagens *case insensitive* nem tentam isso e falham. Linguagens *case sensitive* tentam, mas falham do mesmo jeito.
- Identificadores que diferem apenas em maiúsculas/minúsculas devem corresponder ao mesmo identificador. - Ponto para as *case insensitive*.
- Identificadores que diferem apenas em maiúsculas/minúsculas devem ser proibidos. - Ponto para as *case insensitive*.

Assim, temos no placar dois pontos a favor do *case insensitive* e zero para o *case sensitive* (ou meio ponto, se você quiser considerar que a tentativa frustrada é melhor que nada).

Então o *case insensitive* é melhor? Sim, é melhor que o *case insensitive*, pois é menos confuso, menos propenso a erros e mais natural. Mas isso não significa que não pode existir coisa ainda melhor: Seria possível criar uma linguagem de programação que consiga três pontos?

Sim, se a linguagem de programação visar garantir a consistência dos identificadores sem criar confusão. Para isso, ela teria que ser *case sensitive* na análise do código-fonte, mas *case insensitive* na aceitação deste. Por exemplo, se a linguagem ditar que nomes de variáveis devem ser escritas apenas com minúsculas, então declarar uma variável com o nome `Minha_Variavel` ao invés de `minha_variavel` deveria causar um erro de compilação (ou pelo menos uma *warning*). Por outro lado, se eu declarei `minha_variavel = Minha_Variavel * 2`, o compilador entenderia que `Minha_Variavel` trata-se apenas de `minha_variavel` grafado de forma incorreta, dando um erro de compilação ou *warning* avisando isso, mas ele não iria achar que trata-se de outra variável. Uma linguagem de programação assim conseguiria uma pontuação de 3 e superaria tanto as puramente *case sensitive* quanto as puramente *case insensitive*. Porém não conheço nenhuma linguagem de programação assim, o que mais se aproxima são IDEs de linguagens *case insensitive* que convertem para a forma padrão automaticamente a medida que o programador digita (como ocorre com o Visual Basic).

Há ainda uma desvantagem pouco visada nas linguagens *case insensitive*: Caracteres Unicode fora do padrão ANSI. Um exemplo interessante é o turco, aonde a forma maiúscula de `i` é `İ` enquanto que a forma minúscula de `I` é `ı`. Desta forma, se uma linguagem que admita caracteres internacionais em identificadores for *case sensitive*, quando estes caracteres forem usados pode acabar não sendo claro quais diferentes identificadores são equivalentes entre si para quem não conhece o alfabeto em questão (outro exemplo, pouca gente veria `ΓΩξνσς` como equivalente a `γωΞΝΣΣ`). Para alfabetos como chinês, que não tem o conceito de maiúsculas/minúsculas, essa distinção fica ainda pior, uma vez que tratam-se de letras que não são nem maiúsculas e nem minúsculas. Entretanto, poucas são as linguagens de programação que aceitam identificadores com nomes utilizando caracteres Unicode, e em geral, mesmo nas que permitem, utilizá-los acaba sendo uma má-prática de programação. Por causa disso, no final das contas, esta desvantagem acaba ou pesando muito pouco ou sendo irrelevante na prática.

Comment: Ruby tem regras que influenciam a semântica, não sei se está falando da mesma coisa. Go também tem um pouco disto. Mas no geral as linguagens não o fazem mesmo. Até porque provavelmente é todos considerem que é papel de algo que deva ser externo. Vou votar (amanhã, os votos acabaram) mesmo você tendo sido tendencioso para um lado :P

Comment: @bigown Na verdade, eu tenho como preferência pessoal as *case sensitive*s, mas tentei ser o mais neutro possível e a resposta saiu bem mais a favor das *case insensitive*s. Mais tarde vou pensar com calma como tentar deixar a resposta mais neutra e como levar em conta esse comportamento do Ruby e de outras linguagens aonde a convenção pode ter significado semântico.

Comment: @bigown Eu até tinha começado a escrever sobre Ruby, mas conclui que trata-se de outra coisa. Neste caso, são regras de nomenclatura que alteram a semântica do programa, mas isso pouco ou nada tem a ver com ser *case sensitive* ou não. Afinal, eu poderia ter uma linguagem aonde se eu definir uma classe `Customer` e chamá-la por `CUSTOMER` ou `customer`, tudo estaria ok, mas haveria uma classe `Customers` gerada automaticamente com um método `find_customer_by_id` que eu poderia invocar como `FIND_CUSTOMER_BY_ID`. Ou seja, as regras semânticas quase independem do *case sensitiveness*.

Answer (score 0):

Além da perfumaria, claro (há uma tentativa de padronização do código, o que deveria, não acontece com muita frequência)... 
Há algumas vantagens significativas, como por exemplo em codificações como o base64_encode e base64_decode, criptografia de dados, criação de senhas mais seguras, utilização de rashs e ilimitadas combinações. Indexação de páginas SEO. Alteração comportamental entre métodos similares. Indexação de coisas do mesmo mundo, por exemplo, você pode ter uma classe chamada Animal e uma constante chamada ANIMAL. Mas nada que impeça dela ser descartada, já que boa parte despreza sua importância...

Answer (score 0):

Eu vou mesmo pela definicao.
Case-sensitive é um anglicismo que se refere a um tipo de análise tipográfica da informática. Em língua portuguesa, significa algo como "sensível à caixa das letras" ou "sensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas". Diz-se que um software é case-sensitive ou possui "case sensitivity" quando ele é capaz de analisar uma cadeia de caracteres, avaliar a existência de caixa alta e caixa baixa e comportar-se de diferentes maneiras em função disso.

Case-sensitive significa que caracteres em caixa alta e em caixa baixa são tratados de modo diferente. Por exemplo, as palavras sum e SUM são consideradas diferentes

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente

- Amplia o número de Símbolos que você pode usar
- Padroniza o código
- Facilita a leitura

Answer (score 0):

Em linguagens que exigem declaração de variáveis antes de seu uso a questão de maneira geral é irrelevante.

Em linguagens que não exigem declaração de variáveis antes de seu uso (tipicamente linguagens de script) ser case-sensitive é um tiro no pé, pois um erro na digitação de nomes de variáveis não é um erro sintático, portanto não é acusado como erro pelo compilador/pré-compilador/interpretador/etc.