# Não consigo usar o estilo donut e pie com chartjs!

Tags: javascript, html, cdn, chart, gráfico

Então galera estou usando o chartjs num sistema aqui, mas o estilo pie e donut não exibe no sistema. Eu importei os CDN's:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.js"></script>
```

E fiz um arquivo graph.js para colocar os codigos do chatjs e importo ele no meu head:

```
<code>var ctx = document.getElementById("ChartDonut");
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Pagos","Pendentes"],
        datasets: [{     
            data: [200, 137],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'   
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});</code>
```

O no meu html eu chamo o CANVAS normalmente:

```
<canvas id="chartDonut"></canvas>
```

Mas nem DOUGHNUT e nem PIE funcionam. Alguém sabe o pq?

Comment: Cara, leia bem a documentação do Chart.JS.. você tem o Nugget instalado? ta referenciado no seu projeto? em geral todos os gráficos funcionam de forma igual, precisa de um options e de um data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você possui dois problemas em seu código.

O primeiro é que o `id` do `canvas` é **chartDonut** e no seu script você está usando **ChartDonut**.

O segundo são seus *options*. [Veja a lista do que você pode utilizar.](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#config-options) para esse tipo de gráfico.

Veja abaixo o exemplo do seu código corrigido:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("chartDonut");
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Pagos", "Pendentes"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [200, 137],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartDonut"></canvas>
```

Dicas de leitura:

- [Existem vantagens objetivas em uma linguagem ser “case sensitive” ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74414/20615)
- [Documentação Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)

Comment: Cara valeu mesmo! não tava conseguindo enxergar isso! @Randrade