# Falha ao exibir campos da classe Endereco ao usar método de criação de objeto expresso no C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

O Visual Studio 2017 me sugeriu algo que fiquei surpreso, a criação de objeto sem usar o operador new, fiquei surpreso, pois estou vindo do Java e faz um ano que estou parado e resolvi voltar a estudar.

Pois bem, ao criar um novo objeto Empresa, não aparece os campos da classe Endereco que estão declarados dentro da classe Empresa, mas dentro dela também tem a classe Plano e este sim, aparecem no completar.

Não consigo ver errro, pois as duas classes são quase iguais, tirando o fato que Plano recebe herança da classe Persistant.

Abaixo segue o código para verem das classes:

Classe Empresa

```
namespace Cobranca.pkgModel
{
    public class Empresa : Persistant
    {
        private string nome;
        private string razaoSocial;
        private string cnpj;
        private string status;
        private Plano plano;
        private Endereco endereco;

        public Empresa()
        {
            Endereco = new Endereco();
            Plano = new Plano();
        }

        //métodos getter e setter
    }
}
```

Classe Plano

```
namespace Cobranca.pkgModel
{

    public class Plano : Persistant 
    {
        private string nome;
        private string tipoCobranca;
        private double valor;

        //métodos getter e setter
    }
}
```

Classe Endereco

```
namespace Cobranca.pkgModel
{
    public class Endereco
    {
        private string logradouro;
        private string numero;
        private string bairro;
        private string complemento;
        private string cep;
        private string cidade;
        private string estado;

        //métodos getter e setter
    }
}
```

Abaixo segue o print que tirei da tela

[image: Print da tela ao tentar usar este recurso]

Alguém sabe me responder porque estou passando por isso, sendo que criei um método igual na classe `PlanoDAO` e não apresenta essa falha.

E qual nome desta funcionalidade para eu estudar, isso tem haver com `lambda`?

Obrigado

---

**Resposta:**

Só para constar editei meu código conforme os confrades informaram e ficou assim:

```
            this.Model = new Empresa
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(data["id"]),
                Nome = Convert.ToString(data["nome"]),
                RazaoSocial = Convert.ToString(data["razao_social"]),
                Cnpj = Convert.ToString(data["cnpj"]),
                Status = Convert.ToString(data["status"]),
            };

            this.Model.Plano = new Plano
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(data["plano_pk"]),
                Nome = Convert.ToString(data["plano_nome"]),
                Valor = Convert.ToDouble(data["plano_valor"])
            };

            this.Model.Endereco = new Endereco
            {
                Logradouro = Convert.ToString(data["logradouro"]),
                Numero = Convert.ToString(data["numero"]),
                Bairro = Convert.ToString(data["bairro"]),
                Complemento = Convert.ToString(data["complemento"]),
                Cep = Convert.ToString(data["cep"]),
                Cidade = Convert.ToString(data["cidade"]),
                Estado = Convert.ToString(data["estado"])
            };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse código não deve estar compilando:

```
public Empresa()
{
    Endereco = new Endereco();
    Plano = new Plano();
}
```

Note que você declarou as propriedades `endereco` e `plano` com os nomes completamente em **minúsculas** e como `private`, mas aqui você está usando aquelas com a inicial em maiúsculo.

## Sobre as minúsculas

O [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) é [case-sensitive](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75471/78713), então `Plano`<sup>1</sup> é diferente de `plano`<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1 - Refere-se ao tipo `Plano` (a classe declarada)</sup>
<sup>2 - Refere-se à propriedade do tipo `Plano` cujo nome nessa ocorrência é `plano`</sup>

Nas versões mais recentes do Visual Studio, o destaque apresentado na IDE reforça a interpretação do compilador sobre o código escrito.

Observe :

```
empresa = new Empresa 
{
    Endereco. // AQUI
}
```

A palavra **Endereco** está na cor verde (ou azul, ou azul esverdeado, ou verde azulado ou seja lá o que for), da mesma forma que `Empresa` ou `MySqlCommand`, por exemplo. Isso sugere que naquele momento você está fazendo referência ao Tipo, e não à instância. Portanto, só serão apresentados, caso existam, membros estáticos da classe `Endereco`.

## Sobre o `private`

Ainda que você estivesse usando o nome da propriedade corretamente, você não seria capaz de atribuir o valor dela, pois, assim como é no [java](/questions/tagged/java), o modificador `private` limita o acesso à propriedade ao escopo onde ele é declarado (a própria classe).

## Resolvendo

Então, para corrigir seria:

#### 1 - Mudar os modificadores de acesso dos campos nas suas classes para `public`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public class Endereco
{
    public string logradouro;
    public string numero;
    public string bairro;
    public string complemento;
    public string cep;
    public string cidade;
    public string estado;
}
```

#### 2 - Usar a *propriedade* ao invés do *tipo* nos construtores:

```
var endereco = new Endereco
    {
        logradouro = "algum nome",
        numero = "22A",
        // ... por aí vai
    };
```

> (...)a criação de objeto sem usar o operador new(...)

Eu acho que essa sua afirmação foi fruto da confusão entre **tipos** e **instâncias do tipo**. Então, destruindo os sonhos, para criar a instância do tipo você vai mesmo precisa do `new`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: **Eu posso estar enganado**, mas eu acho que o OP não adicionou na pergunta os  `getter` e `setter`, veja que tem um comentário **//métodos getter e setter**, logo o `Endereco = new Endereco();` vai compilar

Comment: @Barbetta, na classe `Empresa` a propriedade do tipo `Endereco` tem o nome `endereco`. Em nenhum lugar está sendo declarada um variável, campo ou propriedade com o nome `Endereco` (Com a inicial maiúscula). Eu não entender como _getter / setter_ teria relação com isso. Poderia por favor esclarecer?

Comment: @Barbetta, acho que entendi o que você quis dizer. Talvez ele tenha **o campo e a propriedade** declarada na classe, onde a propriedade teria o mesmo nome do tipo. Se for esse o caso, você tem razão, compilaria. E a minha resposta estaria toda baseada na ausência dessa informação.

Comment: Eu acho que ele declarou os `getters` e `setters` "a moda antiga", declarando uma variável privada, e em baixo os `getters` e `setters`, de todo modo, na minha visão sua resposta responde muito bem a pergunta. +1

Comment: @Barbetta sobre a primeira afirmação, sim, não adicionei para não encher demais a pergunta

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza sobre a segunda postagem, eu achava que dentro do corpo de construção do objeto `Empresa`, ele já criaria automaticamente a chamada para `Endereco`, cheguei a pensar em fazer os dois separados sim

Comment: @Barbetta sobre declarar getter e setter a moda antiga, qual é a moda atual? Pois faço uso do `VS` para me ajudar na criação

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza e @Barbetta, vou verificar aqui, pois eu fiz da forma antiga e menos prática, ou seja por exemplo `Empresa.Endereco.Logradouro = "valor";`

Comment: @Macario1983 se a propriedade não tem nada demais no `get` e `set`, a "mada atual" seria `public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }`. Só essa propriedade sem o campo private. Mas baseei minha resposta em uma possível confusão de entendimento da sua parte (e possívelmente da minha, pelo fato de parte do código ter sido omitido - Adminito que nem lembro quando foi que eu usei o termo `getter` ou `setter` pela última vez, é só `propriedade` ou `campo`)

Comment: @Macario1983 talvez seja interessante você avaliar se não vale a pena passar como parâmetro do construtor de `Empresa` um objeto `Endereco` já preenchido.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza eu já instancio no construtor os objetos `Plano` e `Èndereco`. Mas posso avaliar sim, só uma dúvida, esse recurso tem algum nome específico?

Comment: @Macario1983 não. Costumamos chamar de `propriedade autodeclarada` (a que não precisa de um campo `private`)

Comment: O VS tem um atalho para criação de propriedades, na sua classe escreva `prop` e aperte `TAB` duas vezes. Se escrever `propfull` e `TAB` duas vezes, ele cria ela a "moda antiga"

Comment: Caramba, que legal @Barbetta, mas não me responderam, essa forma de criar objeto sem usar parentes no `new`, como se chama, foi o próprio VS que me sugeriu para reduzir código.

Comment: @Macario1983, [o construtor sem parêntesis é conhecido como _construtor padrão_](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) e alimetar as propriedades do tipo no momento da instanciação nós [chamamos de _inicialização_ do tipo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers), isso é um dos vários facilitadores do C#.

Comment: O C# 6 (`Visual Studio 2015`) introduziu alguns [novos facilidatores interessantes com os quais acho que vale a pena você se familiarizar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/Dn879355.aspx).

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, sera de grande ajuda essas referencias, muito dinâmica a linguagem.

Answer (score 2):

O correto seria:

```
Endereco end = new Endereco()
{
    logradouro = "Rua teste",
    numero = "1200"
};
```

Sem utilizar o nome da classe antes do atributo (como você estava fazendo).

Entretanto, há um segundo problema, pois, todas as propriedades das tuas classes são privadas.

Quando eu adiciono no VS Code, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> 'Endereco.logradouro' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Mudando para `public` funcionaria e/ou adicionar a atribuição dos valores à algum método, como o construtor. A escolha depende do objetivo da classe e das suas propriedades. Se é apenas um container, mude para `public`. Entretanto, se é uma necessidade os dados serem populados na criação da instância, use o construtor.

> [...]mas dentro dela também tem a classe Plano e este sim, aparecem no completar.

Como não está nos exemplos aonde que ela está sendo criada, não posso afirmar as diferenças. Se ela estiver sendo declarada dentro do mesmo escopo de sua classe, não ocorrerá erros.

Comment: Amigo, eu omiti as declarações de get e set do código para não alongar demais, mas coloquei um comentário se perceber.

Comment: @Macario1983 sim, isso é verdade. Mas, a forma que estava implementando implicam nas correções acima mencionadas para que funcionem.