# Qual o erro na condicional?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

Qual o erro na condicional abaixo e como resolver?

```
private void Botão_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Pbox.Show();)
        Pbox.Hide();
    else(Pbox.Hide();)
        Pbox.Show();
}

private void Pbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Que confusão de código. `else` não tem condição associada, na condição `if` não pode ter `;`. Depois tem o problema do que você quer fazer que parece errado. Mas antes de ver o que você quer fazer devia aprender a sintaxe da linguagem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A sintaxe está bem errada. De qualquer forma tem um jeito mais fácil de fazer o que deseja:

```
private void Botão_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    PBox.Visible = !Pbox.Visible;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/ChangeVisibility.cs)

Se fosse escrever da forma da pergunta deveria ser assim:

```
if (Pbox.Visible) {
    Pbox.Hide();
} else {
    Pbox.Show();
}
```

Os métodos [`Hide()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.hide?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Hide) e [`Show()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.show?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Show) não retornam nada então não podem ser usados como condição do `if` que espera um booleano. Para saber se o controle está visível use a propriedade [`Visible`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.visible?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Visible). Não é necessário usar uma condição no `else` já que essa propriedade só pode retornar dois valore, ou é verdadeiro, ou é falso, se é verdadeiro executa o bloco do `if`, caso contrário executará o bloco do `else`, independente de qualquer outra coisa. Mesmo que fosse o caso de usar uma condição, só poderia com um `else if`.

Comment: Nem sabia que C# aceitava unicode para nome de funções (e talvez classes): `Botão_Click`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16555/101