# Existem problemas em usar caracteres especiais nos códigos Python?

Tags: python, codificação-de-caracteres, estilo-de-codificação, código-fonte

Pensando em deixar os códigos mais enxutos e elegantes seria possível usar caracteres especiais nos códigos? Traria algum problema?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De forma geral não há problema, tem até uma PEP que fala como fazer isto da forma correta: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/.

Claro que não te livra de ter problemas por causa de alguma ferramenta externa que leia o código e não seja capaz de lidar com isto, de dar problema quando abrir em um editor de texto ruim e outras coisas. Isto foi abordado no geral em [Existe algum problema em usar caracteres Unicode para identificadores em código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16555/101). Eu não abusaria, no máximo usaria acentos.

Enxuto e elegante nem sempre andam juntos (há casos que sim). Não consigo imaginar como caracteres especiais podem deixar o código mais elegante e enxuto ao mesmo tempo, ainda que elegante possa ser um pouco subjetivo.