# Problemas na implementação de métodos

Tags: java, array

Tenho as seguintes classes:

Porta

```
package meu.programa;
public class Porta {
    boolean aberta;
    String cor;
    double dimensaoX;
    double dimensaoY;
    double dimensaoZ;
    void abre() {
        if (aberta == false) {
            aberta = true;
        }
    }
    void fecha() {
        if (aberta == true) {
            aberta = false;
        }
    }       void pinta(String s) {
        cor = s;
    }
    boolean estaAberta() {
        if (aberta == true) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    void mostra() {
        System.out.println("A porta está aberta? " + this.estaAberta());
        System.out.println("A cor da porta eh: " + this.cor);
        System.out.println("A altura da porta eh: " + this.dimensaoY);
        System.out.println("O comprimento da porta eh: " + this.dimensaoX);
        System.out.println("A largura da porta eh: " + this.dimensaoZ);

    }
}
```

Casa

```
package meu.programa;
public class Casa {
    String cor;
    Porta[] portas;
    public Casa (int NumMaxDePortas) {
        this.portas = new Porta[NumMaxDePortas];
    }       
    void pinta(String s) {
        cor = s;
    }
    void quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() {
        int contador = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<this.portas.length; i++) {
            if (????) {
                contador++;
            }
        }
    System.out.println(contador);
    }

    void adicionaPorta(Porta p) {
        for(int i=0; i<this.portas.length; i++) {
            if(this.portas[i] == null) {
                this.portas[i] = p;
            }
        }
    }
    void totalDePortas (Casa casa) {
        int contador = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<this.portas.length; i++) {
            if(this.portas[i] != null) {
                contador++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Numero de portas: " + contador);
    }
}
```

TestaCasa

```
package meu.programa;

public class TestaCasa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Casa house = new Casa(30);
        house.cor = "Verde";
        Porta p1 = new Porta();
        Porta p2 = new Porta();
        Porta p3 = new Porta();

        house.adicionaPorta(p1);
        house.adicionaPorta(p2);
        house.adicionaPorta(p3);

        p1.abre();
        p2.fecha();
        p3.abre();
        p2.abre();

        house.quantasPortasEstaoAbertas();
        house.totalDePortas(casa);

    }
}
```

Como seria a implementação dos métodos quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() e totalDePortas() ???

Answer (score 5):

Você só jogou o seu código e não explicou limitações. O por que das estruturas usadas e pediu para explicar como implementar dois métodos. Irei dar um resumo dos problemas assim como um exemplo de como deveria ser feito.

**1. Array de Porta**

Com o seguinte código:
`portas = new Porta[NumMaxDePortas];` você está criando um vetor de portas com o tamanho máximo o que fará que você tenha todas essas portas sempre que criar a casa e não estará limitando um tamanho máximo para isso. Isso implica que está usando mais memória do que precisa para isso e que terá um vetor grande para percorrer. Uma vez que não armazena a quantidade de portas inicializadas.

Se realmente quiser usar um Array (vetor) de portas, precisará de ter também uma variável inteira para saber qual a quantidade real de portas que possui no momento.

O ideal para este caso seria usar listas, pois isto facilitaria todo o restante da lógica do seu código, visto que te permitiria trabalhar de forma dinâmica e simplificando a lógica necessária.

**2. Métodos não seguem a padronização recomendada**

Em vez de `pinta()`  deveria usar um nome padrão para identificar o que ocorre na classe, como o campo que está alterando possui nome cor, o recomendado seria:

```
void setCor(String cor) {
    this.cor = cor;
}
```

Além de que os métodos criados não explícita qual a visibilidade do mesmo tornando-nos `Package-Private` que é um tipo bem específico de visibilidade o qual não é recomendado para a maioria dos casos.

Os métodos são todos do tipo `void` e você imprime direto neles, enquanto deveria imprimir apenas os resultados obtidos ao chamá-los e no lugar onde os mesmos foram chamados.

**3. Problemas lógicos generalizados**

No método abaixo, você verifica se a variável aberta é verdadeira e se for, retorna verdadeiro. O seu código ficará muito mais eficiente e terá mais sentido se simplesmente retornar a variável em si, não há porque verificar se o retorno será igual ao valor da mesma.

```
boolean estaAberta() {
    if (aberta == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Um outro exemplo de problema lógico é o seguinte método:

```
void abre() {
    if (aberta == false) {
        aberta = true;
    }
}
```

Veja o que fez, se a porta estiver fechada você abre e não faz nada se a mesma já estiver aberta e *o retorno do método é `void`*. Faria sentido essa verificação apenas se o método informasse ao usuário se a porta foi aberta (porque estava fechada). Mas se o objetivo é apenas deixá-la aberta caso chamar poderia fazer dessa forma:

```
public void abre() {
        aberta = true;
}
```

O que economiza uma operação lógica no seu processador.

[Eu criei uma versão desse seu código seguindo as recomendações que falei e as coloquei no seguinte gist.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/36d03e763518bac7229d)

Answer (score 3):

Seu método `totalDePortas` está *quase* bom: a única coisa que está sobrando é esse parâmetro `casa`. Se o método já pertence à classe `Casa` - e você pode acessar o objeto em questão através da palavra-chave `this` (como você já está fazendo) - não há a necessidade de se passar uma *outra* casa como parâmetro.

Quanto ao método `quantasPortasEstaoAbertas`, o que você precisa fazer é obter uma referência para cada porta armazenada, e então poderá chamar métodos e/ou acessar propriedades nesse objeto `Porta`:

```
for(int i=0; i<this.portas.length; i++) {
    Porta p = this.portas[i]; // Pode ser null - lembrar de testar
    ...
    String corDaPorta = c.cor; // Exemplo de propriedade
    boolean portaAberta = p.estaAberta(); // Exemplo de método
```

A partir daí creio que você consegue concluir o exercício por si só. Se sua dúvida não era essa, favor editar a pergunta e esclarecer o que está te trazendo dificuldades.

Nota: Na prática, é bom evitar (em Java) acessar propriedades diretamente, usando métodos acessores em vez disso (*getters* e *setters*). [A resposta do Kyllopardiun](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29338/215) dá um exemplo de um *setter* (`setCor`; poderia ser também `atribuirCor`, se você quiser [manter o código em português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/301/215)). Entretanto, se você ainda não está familiarizado com modificadores de visibilidade (`public`, `protected`, `private`) não precisa se preocupar com isso *por enquanto*.