# É uma prática ruim misturar ingles e portugues no meu código-fonte?

Tags: design-pattern

Vejo que algumas bibliotecas feitas por brasileiros os códigos estão sempre em inglês. Por esse motivo quando crio algumas coisa, sempre faço tudo em inglês.

A questão, é que as vezes vejo códigos onde há mistura de inglês com português.

Algo como:

```
$isUsuarioAtivo = $this->model()->getConsultaTable('minha_tabela');
```

Isso é uma prática ruim?

Devo evitar escrever códigos em português?

Existe alguma diferença de padrão de escrita entre o código da minha aplicação e o código que escrevo para biblioteca?

Comment: Excelente questão! +1

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, isso me lembra coisas como `ZueiraNeverEnds`.

Comment: Tenta usar `LIMIT` em `ZueiraNeverEnds` :D

Comment: Relacionado: [Devo escrever meu programa em inglês ou português?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/301/3117)

Comment: @rray da error 404

Comment: @rray, tem casos que é aceito. Como no caso de bibliotecas que prefixam métodos, como `get`. Aí você é obrigado a usar `getNome`, `getIdade`. A não ser que mude sua tabela para inglês (o que é inviável)

Comment: Eu prefiro escrever em inglês, isso promove para mim(brasileiro) vantagens, como, me aproximar mais da língua nativa da linguagem, me familiarizar com a língua inglesa e com os termos do mundo da programação(que querendo ou não, não surgiu no Brasil). Acho que o mais importante é não misturar os estilos. A ideia é seguir um padrão primordialmente, se você está estendendo ou está em uma empresa onde existe uma forma de escrever um código, acho conveniente seguir o padrão, antes de qualquer preferência própria.

Comment: E também fica inviável acentuar meus método, né, gente. `usuario::éAdministrador()`. Acho que pode dar pau. É melhor `Usuario::isAdmin()`

Comment: Alguém aí deu -1. Será que alguém se ofendeu com a pergunta. Não tenho nada contra quem faça a mistura, só quero saber se isso é uma boa prática, ué... kkkk

Comment: Boa prática é algo subjetivo, assim como pode ver que a pergunta que eu linkei que é bem parecida com a sua foi fechada como principalmente baseada em opiniões, não sei se existe uma resposta certa para a sua pergunta. A propósito, isso não tem nada a ver com design patterns, só que eu não sei exatamente qual tag poderia usar.

Comment: Não fui o downvoter, mas provavelmente há quem pense que essa pergunta é opinativa. Veja a ["Devo escrever meu programa em inglês ou português?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/301/215), +36/-2 porém fechada. A propósito, eu considero esta pergunta duplicata da outra, tem alguma coisa a mais que você gostaria de saber que não é abordada na outra pergunta? (note que ela trata também da questão da mistura inglês/português nos getters e setters, entre outras situações)

Comment: Entendi @Math. Acha que eu deveria especificar a linguagem por exemplo?

Comment: @mgibsonbr, pra mim então pode fechar. As respostas são, sim, satisfatórias. Não vou excluir a pergunta. assim gera mais referência pra outra

Comment: WallaceMaxters não acho não, pois isso é independente de linguagem, poderia ser assim como a outra pergunta usar `estilo-de-codificação`, mas já não sei exatamente como se usar a `nomenclatura`.

Comment: Dei meu voto então. A propósito, como minha resposta à outra pergunta já fala, eu não vejo problemas em usar abreviaturas em inglês com código em português (ex.: `FuncionarioLV` onde "LV" abrevia `ListView`, ou `IFuncionario` para interfaces, etc) mas eu não gosto de misturar nos getters e setters (aliás, eu não gosto de getters e setters, ponto), prefiro `obterConsultaTabela` e `atribuirConsultaTabela`, mas se precisar fazer também não acho nenhum "crime" rsrs. De resto, escrever em inglês ou português é muito mais questão de público mesmo (quem vai desenvolver, quem vai consumir a API).