# Quais as melhores práticas para dar nome às funções?

Tags: funções, estilo-de-codificação, convenções-de-nome

Eu gostaria de saber quais tempos verbais são mais utilizados para dar nomes as funções.

Por exemplo, existe um mais adequado nesse caso hipotético?

```
Calculadora calculadora;
calculadora.soma(3, 4);
calculadora.somar(3, 4);
```

ou

```
int obtemValor();
int obterValor();
```

Qual o melhor tempo verbal para utilizar ao dar nome para as funções?

Comment: Relacionada: [*Devo escrever meu programa em inglês ou português?*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/301/227).

Comment: É uma pergunta mais ampla e específica para C# mas pode ajudar ver como nomear coisas em geral no código: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101

Comment: @bigown Na verdade a pergunta tinha tags de C# e Java, e eu removi. Achei que ela funcionaria melhor se fosse genérica, não sei se fiz bem ou não.

Comment: [Don't Create Objects That End With -ER](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/03/09/objects-end-with-er.html)

Comment: Pelas respostas, eu acho que é ampla a pergunta. Apesar de ter sido fechada como baseada em opiniões, eu acho que o problema é amplitude, em especial dadas a respostas do utluiz e do bigown, que são objetivas, mas em ângulos diferentes do mesmo problema. A resposta do utluiz me parece bem clara se focar em OOP, a do bigown me parece bem abrangente em contextos mais variados de desenvolvimento, mas o importante é que ambas as respostas mostram que dá para se ter respostas bem objetivas. Só que a pergunta não ajuda muito na forma em que se encontra, portanto, concordo com deixar pendente.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## TL;DR

Este é um tema cuja opinião pessoal influencia muito, mas existem algumas boas práticas gerais que podem ser extraídas para nomenclatura e padronização de métodos.

## Padrão

Cada linguagem sugere ou mesmo limite a nomenclatura dos métodos e funções.

Geralmente quando se lida com objetos a preferência é usar o padrão *Camel Case*, isto é, cujas iniciais das palavras são em maiúsculas:

```
comerCoxinha();
```

Já quando falamos de funções em linguagens como Python, PHP ou JavaScript, não é incomum encontrarmos o uso do *underline* ou sublinhado:

```
comer_kibe();
```

Neste aspecto, o importante é manter padrão e consistência tanto em como as palavras que compõem o nome são ligadas quanto em relação ao verbo, idioma e ordem das palavras.

## Classe gramatical e tempo verbal

Diferentes classes gramaticais, tais como verbos, substantivos, preposições e adjetivos podem ser usados para nomear funções e métodos se usados dentro do contexto correto.

### Substantivos e Adjetivos

Substantivos e adjetivos geralmente são usados para nomear variáveis, classes e atributos, já que esses elementos geralmente fazem referência a *algo* ou *alguém*.

Exemplo:

```
class Carro {
}
class CarroColorido extends Carro {
    String cor;
}
carrinhoVermelho = new CarroColorido("vermelho");
```

Note como `CarroColorido` e `carrinhoVermelho` são composições de substantivo e adjetivo que ajudam a compreender a que esses elementos se referem.

### Verbos

Não existe consenso geral, mas muitos livros e implementações sugerem o uso de verbos em métodos, já que eles denotam **ações** de um objeto.

Entretanto, na prática muitos acabam usando tempos verbais diferentes. Por exemplo, alguns entendem que devem usar o infinitivo. Neste caso, o correto para a `Calculadora` seria o método `somar`.

Outros preferem usar o imperativo, como que ordenando o objeto a fazer algo. Neste caso, a ordem para a `Calculadora` seria `some`.

Ao nomear o método `soma`:

- Ou você está usando o imperativo incorretamente, o que não é incomum no Brasil;
- Ou você está usando o substantivo para se referir à ação de `somar`, como que dizendo para o objeto "fazer a soma".

Muita confusão surge porque métodos nomeados em Inglês podem ter tanto a conotação de imperativo quanto de infinitivo. Por exemplo, `execute()` pode ser entendido tanto quanto *to execute* (executar, no infinitivo) quanto *execute* (execute, no imperativo).

## Métodos *getters* e *setters*

Métodos de acesso a atributos geralmente são uma exceção e são nomeados de acordo com seus atributos.

Na maioria das vezes você vai encontrar algo como `setNome(String)` e `getNome()` para, respectivamente, alterar e recuperar o valor de um atributo `nome`.

Também não é incomum encontrar tais métodos sem os prefixos `get` e `set`, tais como `nome()` para recuperar e `nome(String)` para alterar. Particularmente eu prefixo esse padrão.

## Interfaces fluentes

Diversas classes gramaticais acabam sendo bem-vindas quando usamos o padrão *Fluent Interfaces*.

O objetivo aqui é tornar o código o mais legível e fácil de usar e não simplesmente seguir um padrão cegamente.

Um exemplo de uma possível API de acesso a banco de dados:

```
query = Consulta.select("nome").from("cliente")
            .where(Criterio.maiorOuIgual("credito", 1000))
            .and(Criterio.igual("cidade", "Foz do Iguaçu"));
```

Embora eu tenho misturado idiomas, substantivos, preposições, o código acima pode ser facilmente entendido. As partes em Inglês são da linguagem SQL e o resto pode ser compreendido sem consulta à documentação.

## Juntando tudo

Como já disse, não existe regra, mas é recomendável seguir um padrão. Mesmo assim, existem diferentes padrões para diferentes contextos que, aliados a diferentes técnicas, permitem um modelo de classes coerente.

Creio que a pergunta que se deva fazer a cada método criado é:

> Do ponto de vista do código cliente (que chama o método), este nome faz sentido e deixa claro o propósito do método, incluindo seus efeitos colaterais?

Comment: O quarto ponto diz o suficiente do meu ponto de vista. +1.

Comment: Entendo que alguns não gostem de `getNome()` é até acho interessante trocar o `get` por `trazer`, `retornar`, `obter`, etc. para ficar mais consistente, mas desde que li em algum lugar há muito tempo atrás (acho que na especificação do JavaBeans) que se não for usado `get` algumas ferramentas podem não mapear o atributo para o respectivo método _getter_, fiquei com receio de não usá-lo.

Comment: @Piovezan ótima observação. Realmente muitas ferramentas não vão funcionar sem que se siga o padrão Java Beans. Mas no geral as ferramentas e frameworks mais novos fazem uso de anotações e outros mecanismos alternativos para mapear atributos. Eu mesmo quando escrevo alguma rotina de reflexão não faço mais uso de getters ou setters porque dá mais dor de cabeça do que ajuda. É mais fácil acessar diretamente os atributos e adicionar meta informação com anotações, além de ser mais rápido. Em todos os anos, nunca vi um caso onde um método getter justificasse sua existência.

Comment: Sempre que encontrei alguma lógica dentro de um método getter isso geralmente era sinal de problema. Isso é verdade principalmente porque significa que o objeto não é imutável. Acho que a única exceção  são objetos delegate.

Comment: @utluiz Você parece estar falando do [Projeto Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). Interessante, não conhecia. :) Usando esse plugin nas IDEs realmente perde o sentido discutir a nomenclatura dos _getters_, já que eles passam a ser implícitos (invisíveis). Agora, sobre os objetos não-imutáveis, embora imutabilidade seja desejável acho que não existe uma regra de que todos os objetos devam ser imutáveis, embora [haja quem pense que sim](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/09/objects-should-be-immutable.html).

Comment: @Piovezan Não havia pensado exatamente no lombok, mas vale como exemplo. Mas o que eu quis dizer com relação aos getters e setters é que não vale a pena usar o padrão quando ele vai ser útil só em 10% ou menos do código. Eu só uso get e set quando estritamente necessário ou em sistemas legados que adotam esse padrão. Na minha opinião o código fica mais limpo e fácil de entender. Com lombok é melhor ainda, pois os beans ficam praticamente só a definição dos atributos.

Comment: Quando você falou em evitar _getters_ eu havia entendido que se tratava apenas de escondê-los. Mas você está falando de evitar _getters_ e _setters_ como em [Why getters and setters are evil](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html) ou [How do you avoid getters and setters](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/284215/how-do-you-avoid-getters-and-setters), correto? Agora entendi. Aliás, é um ponto tão interessante que acho que poderia ser acrescentado à resposta: "Evite-os quando possível e você não cairá no problema de nomeá-los"

Comment: @Piovezan Na minha resposta, o que eu quis dizer é que eu prefixo não usar os prefixos get e set. Nesse caso, um atributo `nome` poderia ser acessado pelo método `nome()` ao invés de `getNome()`. Por outro lado, estou me referindo a beans e não a outros objetos. Em objetos que fazem algum tipo de processamento ou lógica eu quase nunca crio um getter ou setter.

Answer (score 16):

Cada equipe tem seu próprio padrão, não existe nada universal. Eu estudei o assunto e conclui que cada grupo de pessoas escolhe o que acha melhor, porém encontrei um padrão em códigos mais bem escritos, usualmente por profissionais reconhecidos. Além disso achei alguns guias de estilo que indicam certos padrões, alguns deles que podem ser considerados "oficiais". Eles variavam de acordo com a linguagem. Então vou falar do que eu achei mais comum. Sua milhagem pode variar.

## Algumas "regrinhas"

O mais comum é usar verbos para designar métodos e funções, mMas há casos que outra forma de expressão pode ser útil.

O tempo mais usado é o imperativo, afinal você está mandando executar uma ação. Expressões cujo principal componente são verbos também são usados. Um exemplo clássico é o `getField()` (muito usado em *getters* e *setters*). Isso é facilmente visto em inglês.

Quando os métodos possuem uma função específica eles podem usar outros tempos ou até mesmo serem omitidos dando lugar ao substantivo que ele produzirá. Por exemplo:

- em eventos quando ele indica algo que ainda vai acontecer é comum usar o infinitivo. Quando o evento já aconteceu é mais comum o uso do particípio passado. Quando o evento está ocorrendo é usado o gerúndio.
- se o método ou função irá retornar um booleano é comum ter uma construção específica indicando uma capacidade. Ex.: `is`, `can`, `has`, `isThere` (alguns preferem usar só o `has`), `allow` (que pode ser o mesmo que `can`). Ou em português `é` ou `eh`, `está` ou `estah` (costuma ser seguido de um verbo no particípio ou adjetivo), `pode` (normalmente seguido de um verbo no infinitivo), `tem` (provavelmente seguido de um substantivo), `existe` (seguido de substantivo), `contém`. O plural pode ser usado, ou outra conjugação, ex.: `foiTentado` ou `tentou`. Note o uso da 3a. pessoa. Em alguns casos o verbo pode ser omitido, mas deve evitar fazer isto. Há casos em que o prefixo `Try` indica esta situação, o nome diz que deve tentar e informar se deu certo ou não, é uma convenção. Ele é escrito pensando que vai ser usado em uma pergunta (uma condição/predicado).
- quando o método na verdade retorna uma propriedade, uma característica, um objeto óbvio, enfim, quando é óbvio que o que está querendo é obter uma informação simples, é possível usar um substantivo, mas não se pode abusar disto. Podemos dizer que é uma forma de abreviação do que o método realmente faz. As bibliotecas fazem isto em métodos como `IndexOf` que no fundo está dizendo `GetIndexOf`, ou `HashCode`, que seria `CalculateHashCode`, ou `Size`, que substitui uma propriedade (`GetSize`), `Sin` (`CalculateSin`). Note que há uma diferença entre uma propriedade pura que, em geral, deve ser um substantivo ou adjetivo e um método que está substituindo uma propriedade.

  Quando uma propriedade precisa de um processamento mais que trivial para obter o resultado, é melhor usar um método do que uma propriedade, para deixar claro que há um custo em chamar aquilo. Algumas pessoas acham que ainda assim sempre deveria manter o padrão do verbo e colocar um pelo menos um `Get` na frente. Outras acham que isto provocaria uma proliferação desnecessária de `Get` ou `Calculate` ou outros verbos óbvios. Já vi algumas pessoas separarem em verbos o que muda o objeto e substantivos o que produz um resultado independente, quando há pureza. É algo para considerar quando eliminar o verbo prefixo óbvio.
- em interface fluente ou locais onde o uso tem um objetivo específico, as expressões podem ser usadas de forma um pouco diferente. Fica mais importante a leitura ser fluente, ainda que isto, na maioria das vezes, funcione de forma muito melhor em inglês do que português.

Em português parece que há mais confusão. Alguns entendem que o `get` é `obter`, outros acham que é `obtenha`. Eu vejo as pessoas misturando inglês com português em casos assim, mas quando a pessoa resolve traduzir tudo vejo ser muito comum usar o `obter`. Mas se olharmos estritamente pela língua, isto é um erro. `toGet` seria `obter`. Não bastasse esta análise, alguns guias são bem claros em dizer que o tempo a ser usado é o imperativo, então a tradução seria `obtenha`<sup>Veja comentários abaixo para ver variações de tradução</sup>.

Então o ideal nestes exemplos seria chamar `calculadora.some(3, 4);` e `obtenhaValor();`. Ninguém ponderado vai dizer que está errado usar `calculadora.soma(3, 4);` e `obterValor();`. Alguns até devem exigir que seja desta forma, afinal deve ser o motivo da resposta ter negativos.

A ideia é dar a leitura fluente: "com a calculadora some 3 e 4", ou "com a variável nome separe pela vírgula" (`nome.split(',')`) ou simplesmente "obtenha o valor". Daí algumas até acham que o artigo não deve ser omitido para dar mais fluência. É raro ver códigos que não omitem. Não sei dizer qual é o certo, sei qual eu estou acostumado. Aí entra na opinião pura.

Tente ler no infinitivo, fica parecendo uma máquina falando. É assim que prefere? Já acostumou assim? Ok, não tenho nada contra, é seu gosto. Quer fazer uma tradução mental do que está efetivamente escrito para o que você pensa de verdade, ou seja, escrever no infinitivo mas ler no imperativo? Ok pra mim também. Eu mesmo faço isto em códigos rápidos onde não estou pensando muito em como ele será usado.

Eu vejo usarem o padrão infinitivo em português com frequência. Acredito que seja por seguirem o padrão de outros sem se fazer um questionamento de qual é o correto.

Dentro deste princípio o nome não deve descrever o que a função faz, ele deve indicar o comando. O nome deve indicar o comportamento e não a implementação. É sutil e até subjetivo, mas me parece que o imperativo puxa pelo comportamento e o infinitivo puxa pela implementação.

Um erro comum é tentar usar um método para mudar uma propriedade. Aí o nome já estará errado. É melhor dar um nome de uma ação que por acaso muda uma propriedade. A nomenclatura é outra e fica mais claro qual é o comportamento. Eventualmente mandar mudar a propriedade pode até ser considerado uma vazamento de abstração.

## Conclusão

Mas o que acontece se não seguir este padrão? Nada! Ele continua compreensível. O ideal é que seja consistente sempre. O mais importante é o nome definir bem o objetivo, o que está mandando fazer. O problema fica maior quando nome indica uma coisa e faz outra. Lembrando que pro compilador obviamente não faz a menor diferença.

Não estou aqui tentando mudar o jeito das pessoas fazerem. Se alguém fez de um jeito a vida toda ela não vai querer mudar porque leu o que escrevi aqui, mesmo que ela perceba que faz sentido.

Mantenha a consistência. O importante é saber o que está fazendo. Sempre! E mais importante ainda: regras foram feitas para serem quebradas quando necessário.

A pergunta foca em funções. Para variáveis, classes e outras formas, o padrão deve ser diferente, inclusive sobre o *casing*, eu tenho uma [resposta que fala sobre isto em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101), não faria sentido repetir aqui.

[O assunto rende](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) e cabe [perguntas mais específicas](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming-standards). De fato concordo com o fechamento da pergunta por ser ampla, não por ser baseada em opiniões.

Só para citar algumas referências que achei rapidamente, além da pergunta *linkada* acima onde cito a fonte das recomendações gerais que postei:

- [Documento publicado nas Universidades de Wisconsin/Berkeley e Microsoft Research](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eliblit/ppig-2006/ppig-2006.pdf).
- [Livro sobre C#](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=wVlm5xwMp7YC&lpg=PA248&ots=a3OVI9hWl8&dq=method%20name%20imperative%20style%20naming&pg=PA248#v=onepage&q=method%20name%20imperative%20style%20naming&f=false).
- [O mesmo para C++](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Q7C5i6uHrBkC&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=function%20name%20imperative%20tense&source=bl&ots=MuASIwy-3Y&sig=klnZifotDTXPiD8NlY66c9p3Fgg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiewbfMi4TKAhUJvZAKHVhsAUsQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=function%20name%20imperative%20tense&f=false).
- [Outro livro sobre C++](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=mxZBPSjSEYUC&lpg=PA700&ots=IFpKrpFJtn&dq=function%20name%20verb%20imperative&pg=PA700#v=onepage&q=function%20name%20verb%20imperative&f=false).
- [Livro sobre Microsoft NAV](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=QmoIU1gR8B8C&lpg=PT444&ots=bDTGxa--tM&dq=function%20name%20verb%20imperative&pg=PT444#v=onepage&q=function%20name%20verb%20imperative&f=false) - [web](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsnav-2016/ee414213(v=nav.90)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [Fórum de D](http://forum.dlang.org/post/mailman.295.1331268757.4860.digitalmars-d@puremagic.com).
- [Guia de estilo do LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html).
- [Guia Delphi](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280).
- [Um guia de estilo para Java](http://software.ucv.ro/%7Eeganea/SoftE/JavaCodingStandards.pdf).
- [Outro guia de estilo para Java](http://www.fatih.edu.tr/%7Emoktay/2011/spring/ceng-bilm463/CodeConventions.Java.java-style.pdf).
- [Artigo sobre o uso do JavaBeans](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/01/12/bloated-javabeans-part-ii-or-dont-add-getters-to-your-api/).
- [Lua Sockets](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/tcp.html).
- [Guia de estilo do CQRS](http://cqrs.nu/Faq/commands-and-events).
- [Pergunta no Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/152891/389).
- [*Tag* no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions). E no [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming).
- [GUJ](http://www.guj.com.br/t/nomes-de-metodos/90863) - É uma porcaria, mas os mais articulados mostram que o caminho é o imperativo :D
- [Artigo sobre a naturalidade da linguagem](http://verraes.net/2013/10/verbs-in-class-names/).

Muitos livros e artigos não falam claramente em usar o imperativo, mas todos os exemplos são assim. O livro [Clean Code](http://www.buscape.com.br/clean-code-a-handbook-of-agile-software-craftsmanship-robert-c-martin-0132350882.html) é um dos clássicos para aprender sobre isto. Ainda que eu não concorde com tudo que tem nele. Outro é o [Code Complete](http://cc2e.com/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Como já comentei na outra resposta, acho que o principal motivo para as pessoas usarem o inglês, é que o significado pode variar consoante o contexto em que esta se encontra. Agora a terminação para gerúndios é meio perplexa, e demasiado centralizada, sendo que os termos tornam-se demasiados objectivos, que por norma é que se pretende, mas por outro lado o que se quer evitar numa função. No caso do `get` por exemplo, diria que é outra razão para se escrever nomes incógnitos ao contexto, tanto pode significar `pega`, como `busca` ou outra coisa. E sim, realmente concordo com o caso de bools.

Comment: Sim, eu dei uma simplificada, a tradução pode ser feita para outras coisas, mas o tempo seria este mesmo, então seria `pegue`, `busque`, `traga`. Embora os nomes específicos eu acho que precisam ser bem pensados também, porque pode tudo parecer sinônimo, mas pequenas diferenças pode passar uma ideia errada. Na pergunta relacionada que eu *linkei* acima (no comentário da pergunta) eu falo de vários nomes que são parecidos. Precisa escolher certo. Pode não parecer mas `start` e `begin` são coisas bem diferentes.

Comment: Pra falar a verdade eu acho que o `get` em inglês mesmo é abusado, até porque ele é um coringa na língua, mas na programação, precisamos de mais precisão do que se trata.

Comment: É generalizado, talvez seja esta a razão para que as pessoas o aceitem de bom grado, pode-se usar em vários programas, com diferentes funções e ainda assim vai cumprir o papel que lhe foi atribuído sem quaisquer complicações. Em parte acho que grande parte dos termos em inglês agem da mesma forma.

Comment: Alguém não gostou da resposta. Pelo menos tem várias outras que acharam ela boa.

Comment: Talvez porque ela seja meio normativa quanto ao uso do imperativo. Pode ser discordância nesse ponto. Eu mesmo discordo disso, embora não tenha negativado. Acho que infinitivo e presente do indicativo (`calculaResultado`) são igualmente válidos.

Comment: É provável. Você sabe que o voto não deve expressar discordância, outros já não entendem isto. No final eu digo que cada um pode fazer como quiser. Eu coloquei a forma eu que vejo o uso nos melhores códigos e recomendações existentes em alguns guias. Claro que cada um pode fazer como quiser, mas minha resposta não é só minha opinião, eu pesquisei bastante pra chegar nesta conclusão. Ainda que ela não seja definitiva e universal.

Comment: Melhorei, espero que os negativadores revejam seu voto.

Answer (score 1):

Entre as duas formas que você citou, prefiro a que o verbo está no infinitivo, como obter() e somar().

Procure nomear suas variáveis na mesma língua da linguagem de programação, nesse caso em Inglês.

Cada linguagem possui um padrão e suas boas práticas. Python, por exemplo, possui a [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), um guia de estilo para a comunidade de desenvolvedores. Java deve ter o seu, C++ também e assim por diante.

Além disso, tudo pode variar de acordo com o projeto que você tá trabalhando. Se o pessoal está usando um padrão específico, o ideal seria continuar do jeito que foi começado de forma a manter um padrão.

Fica como dica também o link para os slides [Como nomear as coisas: o maior problema da programação](http://pt.slideshare.net/pirhilton/how-to-name-things-the-hardest-problem-in-programming).

Answer (score 0):

Eu sempre uso o nome resumindo com o mínimo de palavras o que a função irá fazer, exemplo:

```
class Calculadora {
    public static int somar(int a, int b) {
         return a + b;
    }
}
```

Java tem um design de linguagem diferente do .NET Framework, suas funções e classes costumam usar letras minúsculas e maiúsculas para "melhorar a visão do código".

> `somarNumeros` especial do Java
>
> `SomarNumeros` especial do .NET Framework
>
> `somar_numeros` não sei de qual é, mas na minha opinião é o pior jeito de nomear algo.

## Nomes em português?

Em minha opinião, eu prefiro usar mesmo o Inglês para quaisquer linguagem eu for usar, é muito mais bonito usar o Inglês para nomear uma função do que o Português.

```
int obterValor(); 
int getValue();   //Tudo em inglês, melhor ainda
```

Definir nomes de funções ou tipos depende do escritor do código, não é bom misturar Inglês com Português no seu código, pode causar uma confusão na hora de *entender* o código. Você deve nomear o método com o que ele vai fazer, uma função com o que ela vai fazer e o que ela vai retornar, exemplo:

```
int getAlunoFromIndex(int i, string[] alunos) {
     return alunos[i];
}
```

E não assim:

```
int ObterAlunoPeloIndice(int i, string[] alunos) {}
```

> Sempre você irá executar uma função *~~ futuro*
>
> Você vai obter um valor *~~ futuro*
>
> Aquela função vai usar esse método aqui *~~ futuro*

Enfim, essa pergunta depende muito de quem vai escrever o código. Recomendo usar o nome de funções no *futuro do indicativo*, e também se adaptar à sintaxe da linguagem. Exitem linguagens que usam todos os métodos EM LETRAS MAÍUSCULAS, você gostaria de ver um método em maiúsculo e outro em minúsculo no seu código? Ia dar um *toc*, não é?

```
private int OBTER_VALOR = 0;
private int getIdade = 15;
private int ObterPropriedade = "Foo Bar";
```

Causa uma confusão, então, você escolhe o jeito que vai usar no seu código.

Comment: Eu normalmente uso tudo em inglês, mas que fica esquisito quando precisa usar um "CPFDigit()",  "BoletoVerify()", etc fica kkk.

Comment: @Bacco acho que nesses casos específicos devemos usar o nome em português pois tem mais sentido devido ao contexto.

Comment: Acho que na maior parte das vezes as pessoas escrevem em inglês porque lhes facilita a escrita, ou seja, nomes relativamente curtos, ainda com o mesmo significado que teriam em português, e chegam a ter mais lógica, por se adaptarem ao contexto, para além de ser uma opção viável para internacionalização do script, sendo que se trata de uma língua dominante.

Comment: @Bacco : `BoletoVerify()` é bem esquisito mesmo pq está errado até em Inglês. Mesmo que a pessoa opte por não traduzir "Boleto" pro Inglês, o verbo deve vir na frente do substantivo: `VerifyBoleto()` não é (tão) estranho e é mais correto.

Comment: @MestreLion se for pensar do ponto de vista da língua sim, mas normalmente uso as palavras para fazer agrupamento das funções: `BoletoIsso` `BoletoAquilo` `BoletoAquiloOutro` (para você agrupar as funções por "Boleto") - Não se trata de composição de frase, e sim de organização de código - Isto posto, concordo com você que fica mais estranho, mas é uma "desordem consciente". Eu tenho uma certa preferência por tratar como prefixo na mesma coleção. Note que o caso do dígito vem o CPF antes também, como viria CpfVerify ou CpfFormat, etc (que apesar de ordem invertida, colocam o assunto primeiro)

Comment: Chamemos de "Namespace de pobre" ;)

Comment: @MestreLion e `boleto.Verify()` é adequado? Porque é o que todo mundo adora usar.

Comment: `Bool VerificaBoleto(Boleto boleto) { }`

Comment: @Bacco: ah, ok, enquanto "namespace de pobre" é válido sim. Nesse caso eu talvez usasse `_` como separador pra deixar bem claro a intenção de agrupamento/namespace. Mas estamos falando de funções "puras" né? Pq se estamos em classes, ver todos esses métodos com prefixo `BoletoXxx()`/`boleto_xxx()` são forte indício que uma classe `Boleto()` tá implorando pra ser criada :-)

Comment: @Maniero: `boleto.Verify()` enquanto método de uma classe `Boleto()` eu acho super válido sim (mas deixaria em minúscula). Eu prefiro programar em Inglês pra não cair no eterno dilema infinitivo/imperativo/indicativo (calcular, calcule ou calcula?), mas deixaria boleto sem traduzir pq não tem equivalente direto (slip? ticket?). Então, sim, `boleto.verify()` it is :-)

Comment: @Bacco, complementando seu ótimo comentário: ao fazer troca de ordem pra fins de agrupamento tem que ter _muito_ cuidado (e ser _muito_ consistente no uso) por conta de ambuiguidades em alguns verbos: em linguagem natural, `CpfFormat` e `FormatCpf` são coisas distintas, o primeiro pode ser lido como um substantivo, "o formato do CPF", tipo a máscara a ser usada ao se formatar o CPF pra exibição ou digitação.

Comment: @CypherPotato: Já estamos saindo um pouco do escopo da pergunta, mas acho que uma função que recebe um objeto pra verificá-lo é uma modelagem OO fraca. verificação deveria ser um método da classe do objeto, e não uma função/método externo de outra classe que recebe o objeto.

Comment: Mais de três anos depois da publicação e vamos tornar a resposta como Fora de escopo.

Comment: @MestreLion de acordo, note que eu não gosto dessa mistura, realmente era só para exemplificar mesmo. Em Harbour, por exemplo eu uso o _ como você comentou: `namespacedepobre_NomeDaFuncao()` (a linguagem não tem namespaces de fato, e criar classe pra isso, em especial se tratando de compilar para linguagem intermediária, gera todo um custo que não justifica o uso para algo que não vai ser OO de fato)