# Por que usar o "is" no início variável em Kotlin?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, kotlin, convenções-de-nome, booleano

Qual o motivo de usar o `is` na frente da variável. Exemplo de código fonte. Sei que tem algo a ver com o `set`.

```
class Rectangle( val height: Int, val width:Int)
{
    val IsSquare: Boolean

    get(){
        return height == width
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isso nada tem a ver com Kotlin ou outra linguagem, é só uma convenção que se costuma usar para indicar que a variável é booleana, é para dar legibilidade mostrando a semântica dela.

Tão pouco tem a ver com `set`, embora possa ser usado nele.

Alguns consideram uma forma disfarçada de [notação húngara](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/101), outros consideram que não já que mostra o significado real da variável. Se tirar esse prefixo não dá para saber o que é, se colocar outra coisa pode ficar maior e ainda não ser adequado.

Claro que o `is` é só um exemplo que diz se algo é ou está em determinado estado. O `has` também é muito usado para indicar se tem algo. Mas pode usar várias outras formas para prefixar um substantivo e adjetivar seu significado, como `can` para indicar se tem aquela capacidade, só para citar mais um exemplo.

Tem quem use em português, o que pode ser melhor por indicar se é um estado "transitório" (`está`) ou "permanente" (`é`).

Falo mais sobre isso em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106069/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).