# Objeto vem pro bean com todos campos em branco JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Eu tenho uma lista de objetos Predio que está sendo iterada no meu xthml
Aí, pra cada iteração, eu crio um panel e em cada panel eu exibo o nome de cada um dos predios da lista e um botão que chama um o método carregaPredio(Predio predio) no Bean. Esse método apenas carrega o atributo predio do bean com o argumento recebido. Após isso, um dialog é aberto e as informações do predio clicado é exibido.
Os nomes dos itens estão sendo renderizados perfeitamente na tela. Porém, quando o dialog abre, os campos vêem em branco.
Alguém pode imaginar o que seja?
Segue o código :

```
<c:forEach items="#{predioBean.listaPredios}" var="entry">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText value="#{entry.nome}" />
        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{predioBean.carregaPredio(entry)}"  oncomplete="PF('DetalhesPredioDialog').show();"/>
    </h:panelGroup> 
</c:forEach>

 <!-- ********** DIALOG DETALHES PREDIO ********** --> 
            <p:dialog header="#{predioBean.predio.nome}"  widgetVar="DetalhesPredioDialog" modal="false" resizable="false" width="400" height="150" >
                <h:panelGrid id="pnlDetalhesPredioDialog" style="margin-bottom:10px;" columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['nome']}"  />
                    <p:inputText size="30" id="nomePredio" value ="#{predioBean.predio.nome}" />

                    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['descricao']}"  />
                    <p:inputText size="30" id="descricaoPredio" value ="#{predioBean.predio.descricao}"/>

                    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['endereco']}"  />
                    <p:inputText size="30" id="enderecoBanco" value ="#{predioBean.predio.endereco}" />

                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['edita']}" icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="#{predioBean.editaPredio}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>
```

Agora o Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PredioBean {

private Predio predio;
private List<Predio> listaPredios;
private PredioDAO predioDao;

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    this.predio = new Predio();
    this.predioDao = new PredioDAO();
    this.listaPredios = contaErrosDoPredio();
}

public void carregaPredio(Predio predio) {
    this.predio = predio;
}

}
```

Obrigada

Comment: Já tentou dar um update no panelGrid do dialog ao clicar no botão? update="pnlDetalhesPredioDialog"

Answer (score 1):

Tathiana,

Seu exemplo contém vários prováveis problemas:

1. Seu `dialog` está dentro de um `form`?
2. O método `editaPredio` não está no seu `ManagedBean` ou você não colocou?
3. Seu `commandButton` deverá processar e atualizar as informações necessárias

Se você deseja utilizar o ajax, que faz mais sentido, seu botão deverá ser algo assim:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg['edita']}" icon="ui-icon-pencil" 
                 action="#{predioBean.editaPredio}" 
                 process="@this pnlDetalhesPredioDialog" update="@form"/>
```

Caso não deseje utilizar ajax, simplemente adicione `ajax="false"`:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg['edita']}" icon="ui-icon-pencil" 
                 action="#{predioBean.editaPredio}" ajax="false"/>
```

Procure utilizar nomes de funcões com a ação que ela faz, de preferência utilizando verbos no infinitivo, apenas questão de boas práticas e melhor visualização do seu código:

- `carregaPredio` para **`carregarPredio`**
- `editaPredio` para **`editarPredio`**

---

#### Referência:

- [Quais as melhores práticas para dar nome as funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106061/)