# Forma mais adequada de nomear uma lista

Tags: java, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação

Olá gostaria de tirar uma duvida sobre nome de atributos. Qual seria o modo mais adequado de nomear uma lista? Vamos supor que eu tenho um atributo que é uma lista de UFs. Qual seria o jeito correto de nomeá-la? `ufs`? `listaUfs`?

No livro Clean Code, o autor Robert Cecil Martin diz:

> " The name of a variable, function, or class, should answer all the big questions. It
>   should tell you why it exists, what it does, and how it is used. If a name requires a comment,
>   then the name does not reveal its intent. "

Tendo isso em mente eu pergunto: colocar a palavra "lista" nesse atributo é uma informação relevante ou é redundância?

Além disso gostaria de saber se é correto usar palavras no plural pra nomear um atributo ou não?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como escrever um código legível e de fácil manutenção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais as melhores práticas para dar nome as funções \[fechada\]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106061/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Por que não comentar o código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/399158/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Como saber a medida certa de comentários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15488/3774)

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro, [o que você chama de atributo na verdade se chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Em geral `listaUfs` é uma forma de [notação húngara](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/101) e isto não costuma ser considerado adequado. Provavelmente só `ufs` é a melhor coisa. Para listas e outras coleções o plural costuma ser mais interessante, mas para campos que não sejam coleções não é adequado. Só não sei se deveria ser uma lista com isto, talvez outra forma poderia ser melhor, mas depende do contexto. O mais importante é que `lista` é redundante na maioria dos cenários, mas pode ter algum que possa fazer sentido.

Um caso que pode ser útil é quando o nome da variável deve afirmar o detalhe de implementação e ser uma lista, mas isso é muito raro e quase sempre um erro.

Em alguns casos é melhor procurar outro nome mais relevante, mas nem sempre é fácil achar, este mesmo eu não sei um melhor. Alguns possuem coletivos. Mas é preciso tomar cuidado, já vi gente sugerindo que uma lista de jogadores na verdade é um time, mas também tem quem discorde afinal um time não é só uma lista de jogadores, um time provavelmente até é um objeto que tem uma lista de jogadores, entre outras coisas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -4):

Você pode nomear da forma que mais se adequar ao seu projeto. A única regra que você deve ter em mente é sempre seguir o padrão camelcase. Começando sempre com letra minúscula na primeira palavra e maiúsculas na Segunda em diante. Exemplo:

listaUfs ou listUfs ou listaDeUfs....

em fim...

Comment: `minhaArrayDeUfs` é adequado para você?

Comment: sim se só você for o único que vai mexer no código kk

Comment: Acho que não é bom escrever um código que só você entenda. Pode ser que você abandone esse código e depois dum tempo precise dar manutenção. Aí só Deus vai saber dar manutenção nesse código, e tenho certeza que ele não vai querer fazer isso. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/3774

Comment: Bom isso é um ponto de vista...... Tem gente que acha tudo na bagunça e se perde na arrumação e vice-versa. Como explicar isso? No meu caso, eu fui aprendendo tudo que sei sozinho. Não tenho faculdade em TI mas me considero um bom programador de Android. Tenho meus próprios métodos de arrumação e não me perco nunca neles...