# Programar em inglês entra em conflito com a construção de uma linguagem ubíqua?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, ddd, convenções-de-nome

Eu já encontrei na internet alguns argumentos a favor de programar em inglês, ao invés de programar em português, sendo que inclusive já temos uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/301/devo-escrever-meu-programa-em-ingl%C3%AAs-ou-portugu%C3%AAs) questionando qual seria a maneira recomendável.

Acontece que fiquei pensando nisso pelo ponto de vista do Domain Driven Design. Nessa metodologia de desenvolvimento um foco muito grande é colocado na construção de uma linguagem ubíqua. Isso significa que o código deve falar a mesma linguagem do domínio.

Isso significa que nós codificamos usando os termos do domínio. A construção da linguagem ubíqua é o que nos permite construir o modelo e identificar os objetos e comportamentos. O código acaba espelhando a linguagem ubíqua que foi estabelecida.

Acontece que se programarmos em inglês, já vamos ter uma quebra, aparentemente. Afinal, o código vai usar outros termos, diferentes dos termos do negócio. Ora, se o negócio é de um país em que se fala português, seus termos vão ser em português. A partir daí passa a existir uma camada de tradução entre o código e o negócio.

Nesse sentido, programar em inglês entra em conflito com a construção de uma linguagem ubíqua? Para estabelecer uma linguagem ubíqua e utilizar a mesma no desenvolvimento devemos "fazer tudo em um idioma só"?

Comment: Tem coisas que são utópicas. Mas tem gente que as persegue porque alguém disse que é bom. Desde que eu comecei nesse vida, e já são décadas prometem ferramentas milagrosas, alguns as "compram", mas só as que não fazem milagre sobrevivem.

Comment: No meu ponto de vista, se você esta desenvolvendo algum framework, library, etc, o melhor seria usar o inglês. Primeiro porque ele pode ser usado em varias aplicações, e segundo que hoje em dia, é comum termos contribuições de pessoas estrangeiras. Já no caso de um sistema, dependendo do seu tema, acredito que seja interessante usar a lingua nativa. Um ERP por exemplo, seria muito complexo achar traduções para termos contábeis e fiscais. A unica coisa estranha, seria misturar os dois, como `IsCombustivel` ou `GetValor`

Answer (score 3):

A resposta, como você pode imaginar, é de fazer raiva. Mas é a realidade. Depende...

Há mais ou menos um ano e meio precisei desenvolver um sistema simples, mas era para uma multinacional. Havia um layout de importação de 
um determinado ERP para gerar arquivos com todos os termos comerciais em inglês.

Bill to customer (faturar para o cliente)
Ship to customer (entregar para o cliente)
.
.
.

Ou seja, o domínio deste cliente considera termos em inglês, portanto, eu fiz o mesmo desta forma.

Quando o sistema não é para cliente que envolva intrinsecamente ingles, ou outro idioma, além do portugues, prefiro fazer em portugues, sem dúvida.

Imaginando, por exemplo, que o cliente para o qual vc está fazendo o sistema é brasileira, e principalmente, quando trata meandros fiscais/tributários, se vc usar
ingles, a coisa vai ficar feia...

Portanto, pensando em um sistema que trata alguns impostos, além de usar nomes pronunciáveis, existem abordagens que vc pode implementar, até mesmo
para fixar o dominio. Segundo o próprio Evans, "...nos tornamos especialistas de novos domínios a cada projeto..."

Quando vc precisa considerar questões fiscais/tributárias e ainda contábeis, vc pode desenhar, tipo no guardanapo de papel mesmo, como ficaria...

Entidade                               forma curta para instanciar a classe

CentroDeCusto                          cCusto ou cC

Natureza                               natureza

ContasDeResultado                      CResultado

DemonstrativoDeResultadoDoExercicio    dRE

ImpostoSobreServicosDeQualquerNatureza ISSQN

ImpostoDeImportacao                    iI

CodigoFiscalDeOperacoesEPrestacoes     CFOP

Fica muito mais intuitivo modelar as classes relacionadas a impostos em portugues mesmo, neste exemplo. Este é o meu voto, desde que você analise se de fato o código
além de servir ao cliente e o domínio do mesmo, também sirva a você.

Espero que tenha contribuído para elucidar o caso, mesmo que não tenha esgotado.