# DDD restringe escrita de código baseado no idioma do cliente?

Tags: java, c#, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Meu pouco conhecimento sobre DDD foi intimado e gostaria de saber mais sobre.

O DDD restringe a escrita de código baseado no idioma do cliente por conta da linguagem ubíqua?

Comment: Que restrição está falando? Está dizendo que só pode fazer assim?

Comment: Bem... Isso vai do contexto e do cliente. Mas, o cliente sendo brasileiro, eu tenho que colocar meus códigos em português. Eu me sinto mais confortavel em inglês...
Por exemplo... Imagine o seguinte contexto:
RelatorioFactory... é feio português com inglês... ClienteController ... Isso quebra um pouco as boas práticas...

Comment: Fortemente relacionada/duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139272/357

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primeiro, tenho que dizer que acho uma bobagem muitas das regras que o pessoal cria. Especialmente em DDD tem um monte que por si só acho bobas, não que tudo seja ruim nele.

DDD diz que a linguagem (e aqui não importa se é uma língua, é para usar as mesmas palavras para evitar ambiguidade de entendimento) usada no código deve ser a que o cliente usa. Seu cliente usa tudo em inglês? Se não usa, então tem que ser em português, segundo a regra. Tem que ser algo que o consumidor do sistema entenda.

Inclusive se o cliente não usa inglês você acha que vai dar os nomes certos? Pode ocorrer, mas eu sempre vi aberrações de tradução, nem o cliente, nem ninguém usava aqueles termos, apenas o programador que criou o código. Ele se julgava fluente em inglês mas fazia traduções literais, e nem usava DDD.

Já parou pra pensar que alguns termos são intraduzíveis? Mesmo. Um exemplo é ICMS.

Essa regra faz sentido? Na teoria sim, na prática ocorre essas coisas que você demonstrou no comentário. Mas o problema não é misturar, o problema é que essa tão falada linguagem ubíqua não costuma ocorrer de fato. O cliente não entende o que você faz, isso sempre foi uma falácia. Se até programadores não entendem bem o que estão fazendo imagina quem é leigo. Essa regra é um idealismo. E não vi evidências que comprovem que ela sequer é útil de verdade mesmo que ela seja feita perfeitamente. O que mais vejo é as pessoas que usam DDD reclamando que não deu certo ou que não viram vantagem, e vejo consultores em DDD dizendo que eles não souberam fazer, mesmo que tenha sido eles que treinaram a equipe pra fazer o DDD.

Uma das críticas que faço ao DDD, especialmente a tal linguagem ubíqua é que só funciona bem quando não há interligação do domínio com o mecanismo, o que na prática é o oposto do que ocorre. Talvez tenha uma regra que diz que esses casos não precisam seguir a mesma coisa, mas não sei, não sou especialista.

Pra mim, bom senso e trabalho duro sempre superou qualquer metodologia, até porque nenhuma metodologia toma decisões por você e são elas que contam pro resultado final. Mas se for seguir essa regra específica tem que entender a motivação dela, é a linguagem ubíqua foi criada para comunicar melhor com o cliente, então isso ocorrerá no seu caso se fizer em português ou inglês? Se não é para comunicar melhor com o cliente, aí o problema é pior porque nem sabe porque está usando DDD, só o faz por estar na moda. Pense nisso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).