# Qual a alternativa do 'And' no Português para nomes de variáveis e métodos?

Tags: java, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação, camel-case

Uma dúvida que sempre me amola quando estou em um projeto Java no qual usamos termos em português é lidar com nomes de métodos ou variáveis que representam, de alguma forma, duas coisas e preciso mencionar ambas no nome do método/variável. Em inglês, e na mesma situação, os nomes ficam melhores.

Um exemplo, se estou em um código em inglês e tenho uma variável que contém o nome e sobrenome da pessoa, eu posso ter:

```
firstAndLastName
```

Simples e fácil de ler, graças ao `And`. Mas em português o nosso `And` é o `E`, o que fica muito ruim de ler no código na minha opinião, pois as letras maiúsculas acabam grudadas:

```
primeiroESegundoNome
```

Não sei quanto a vocês, mas esta parte `ES` me dá uma travada na leitura de qualquer código.

Normalmente, acabo usando umas destas alternativas:

```
primeiroSegundoNome
primeiroComSegundoNome
```

Resolve em alguns casos, fica só estranho em outros, mas em alguns não resolve. Exemplo, se tenho um método que verifica se as datas existem e são iguais, querendo dar ênfase nesta situação, nenhuma das formas abaixo atende bem:

```
hasDatasIguais
hasDatasComIguais
isDatasExistemIguais
isDatasExistemComIguais
```

Em termos de nome, ficaria melhor mesmo `hasDatasEDatasIguais`, `hasDatasESaoIguais`*..., mas voltamos ao problema inicial.

Este é um problema que incomoda vocês também? Como vocês agem em casos similares?

<sup>* Aqui misturei o termo inglês `has` com português, mas isto é um outro assunto</sup>

Comment: Caramba, pensei que só eu sofria com isso.

Comment: Fiquei curioso com as resposta que você terá para essa pergunta, muito interessante!! Só uma coisa, (baseado em opinião)no método de data eu usuário o `Has`, que em tradução livre seria "tem data existente" invés de "é data existente"

Comment: @Barbetta, verdade. Poderia ser `hasDatasESaoIguais`. Vou corrigir.

Comment: @Dherik mas o "E" ainda é muito estranho rsrs ;P

Comment: Essa é uma das razões que me leva a usar inglês no nome das variáveis.

Comment: Essa e por as estruturas da linguagem serem em inglês. Acho muito mais fácil ler `while not finished` do que `while not finalizado`, por exemplo.

Comment: Eu prefiro utilizar inglês na maior parte dos casos já por causa dessas ocorrências, mas também pode manipular um pouco o Português. `primeiroMaisSegundoNome` e `existemDatasIdenticas` , no último caso 'existe' não tem muita importância a meu ver, pois se são idênticas automaticamente existem. A menos que esteja a comparar um objecto. But still...

Comment: Eu queria ver tudo em inglês em domínios que são usam muito termos locais, e em equipes que não tem profundo domínio do inglês no assunto, o que é muito comum. A linguagem nativa ajuda definir o que é mecanismo e o que é domínio. Nem tudo precisa ser lido naturalmente. E se for tudo em inglês nem sempre é intuitivo, muitas vezes cria uma carga cognitiva maior. Embora realmente nossa língua não é das mais adequadas.

Comment: @ramaral, concordo, mas normalmente os termos de negócio são em português, aí acaba misturando inglês com português inevitavelmente, o que também fica estranho rs.

Comment: Eu costumo usar termos de negócio e do domínio em português, mas não traduzo as convenções de código, então sempre acabo com coisas como `getCPF` ou `setNotaFiscal` - há quem defenda que deveria ser `pegaCPF` ou `obtemCPF`, mas neste caso específico, muitas APIs como o JSF sempre procuram o getter e setter automaticamente e não vale a pena traduzir estes métodos. Já operações de negócio (`fazIsso`, `processaAquilo`) eu acho melhor usar os termos que o negócio usa, para facilitar as coisas. Acho que não há uma regra de ouro para isso, e deve ser analisado caso a caso.

Comment: O comentário do @lazyFox é exatamente a solução que eu usava!

Comment: @lazyFox, elas podem ser iguais mas ambas nulas. Por isto a ênfase no `existe` :). Mas é só um exemplo específico do problema com `And`.

Comment: Correto, mas agora depende do seu método de comparação e se existe a necessidade de  considerar nulos

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/301/devo-escrever-meu-programa-em-ingl%C3%AAs-ou-portugu%C3%AAs

Comment: Eu também sofro muito com essa dúvida. Geralmente, tento mudar nomes como "primeiro e segundo nome" para coisas como "nome completo". Mas boa pergunta +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primeira opção: aceita que dói menos :) Se tiver um padrão quando bater o olho em duas maiúsculas seguidas, ainda mais uma sendo `E` já ligará rapidamente o que é, depois de algum treino.

Também pode usar algumas variações ruins

```
isDatasExistemTambemIguais //Fica longo, mas aceitável
isDatasExistemTbIguais  //Menos legível, mas nada crítico
isDatasExistemE_Iguais //Foge do padrão normalmente usado, mas resolve
isDatasExistemAndIguais //Esquisito, mas válido, há precedente
isDatasIguaisSeExistirem  //Questão se interpretação
isDatasExistentesMasIguais //Mais para ter opções
```

Dá para fazer outras combinações partindo destas.

Mas como o `E` pode ser implícito em algumas situações é mais fácil reescrever, eu ficaria com

```
TemDatasIguais
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/VariableNameStyle.java).

Se não existe uma ou mais datas implica que elas não são iguais. Claro se todas não existem até podemos dizer que são iguais, mas de certa forma elas sequer são comparadas.

Se realmente puder existir uma situação que a concatenação precisa ser explícita aí teria que usar alguma outra palavra, ou aceita a esquisitice que fica o *casing*.

Eu usaria `Eh` ou `É` no lugar do `is`. No começo acho que o *casing* é menos importante, e o acento ajuda diferenciar. Veja: [Existe algum problema em usar caracteres Unicode para identificadores em código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16555/101).

Comment: `"Aceita que dói menos"` - O resumo preciso da minha filosofia depois de perder todas as batalhas para escrever código em Inglês nos projetos da faculdade.

Comment: @Maniero, gostei da resposta. Minha objeção só vai para o uso do `eh`. Isto sempre me lembra do vocabulário "miguxês" :P. Acento em código eu, sinceramente, nunca vi e sempre que alguém esquecia um no código este era "condenado" pelos demais, mas nunca me questionei se isto é realmente um problema ou não. Acredito que por possíveis diferenças de configuração de IDE entre os devs, acaba sendo melhor evitar.